# Eclipse says there's an error, but where?

Tags: eclipse

If I do Project -> Clean and then Build, everything is fine, but if I try to run this Android-project, a dialog comes up: "Your project contains errors. Fix them before running application", and there's a red cross on the project name.

There's no cross on any item in the project tree, and nothing in Console view or LogCat view. So, where's the error?

The only difference for this project and an earlier working version was that I removed a link to an external .jar file, created folder "lib" and put the .jar in there, and added that .jar to the build path. The .jar is the exact same as the external referenced.

[image]

Comment: Now I tried to remove the lib folder and added the external reference .jar again, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may need to Refresh your project in order to see the errors.  Also, bring up the Problems tab for more specific information (Window > Show View > Other > General > Problems).

Comment: That view showed a problem similiar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins and that's how I solved it. Thanks.

Comment: The Problems view is what I forgot to check out. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse shows the Errors in the Problems View.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess but I would check the build path (right click the project and see), if some entry is missing there then there can be this error sign. Another reason of this red error sign is, if this project includes some other java project in path which has any errors (compilation or build path), then it will also display errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I deleted a library, but did not remove it from the build path. Go to Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries. And see if you see something like "can't find library" and remove it.