# Android: Eclipse won't run Android projects

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

I have an issue where every time I try to run a project (that has normally run before), eclipse tells me I have compile errors. There are no errors in the code, the console is empty and I haven't changed anything in the build path...recently. I can actually export the application and install it on the phone and it runs fine, but playing from Eclipse if broken for some reason. I wish I could give more info, but there is nothing to show :/

EDIT: I can't even run a new project. I just tried to make a Hello World app and it still says I have compilation errors. I don't know if this might help so I figured I would add it.

EDIT 2: Problems tab stats this: "Description Resource Path Location Type Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 3/30/12 10:10 AM TestApp Unknown Android Packaging Problem."

FIXED: [debug.keystore issue fixer upper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

Help?

Comment: have you tried by cleaning and rebuilding your project

Comment: Yes. When the error is thrown, I can clean the project. But if I try to run it again, then it gives me the same error. I wanted to know if something else was wrong, so I cleaned and then exported the application to install on the device and it works fine. I am lost...

Comment: What exactly does Eclipse tell you about compile errors?

Comment: You are building the project with maven?

Comment: What do you see from the `Problems` tab?

Comment: Title of message box says "Android launch." Then it says: "Your project contains error(s). Please fix them before running your application." I have even tried some of my older applications that are archived and in pristine condition. I have switched workspaces and I have all of the up to date SDK modules loaded into Eclipse. I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: Problems tab says: "Description Resource Path Location Type Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 3/30/12 10:10 AM TestApp Unknown Android Packaging Problem." I didn't have the problems tab open so I didn't see this. I still don't know what it means though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to window --> preferences --> Android --> build,  see where Eclipse points to your debug.keystore, go there delete it, and relaunch Eclipse.

Comment: Found it the same time you replied :) Thanks for the help. I'm gonna link to the original SO thread that fixes this.