# Issues while creating an android project

Tags: android, eclipse

**Eclipse IDE:** eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32(3.7.2)
**SDK:** android-sdk_r18-windows
**OS :** Windows7.

I have done all configuration to create an ANDROID project according to the android developers guide with the above things.But after creating an android project with the name 'demo_android',the error log shown up as

**Error log**

Failed to load properties file for project 'demo_android'

Keybinding conflicts occurred.They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.

A conflict occurred for CTRL+DEL: Binding(CTRL+DEL,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result.removeInstance,Remove Result,,Category(org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result.category,SQL Results View,null,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+DEL,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.internal.action.RemoveAction,Remove,
        Remove selected Pictogram Elements,
        Category(org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.Graphiti_Category,Edit,Graphiti Diagram Editor,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+D R:

A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+X R:

A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+I....

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this problem?

Thanks for your Time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your debug keystore?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins), if you do not know how.