# properties failed to load any new project

Tags: android, properties

I have been trying to sort this problem out for days now and I still have no luck. Every time I try to make a new project it says failed to load properties. Were it all started was when I made a new workspace (didn't delete the old ) I thought I would read about it before I do it. When I started the new workspace it began to say this. It also said my DDMS was missing.

So I looked about and tryed to find the solution but no luck. So I uninstalled eclipse and the plugging. A reinstalled them all back. And still doing it

http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/3898/fixx.png

thank you

http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/9863/kaka1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your debug keystore?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins), if you do not know how.

Comment: i cant delete it for some reason i not had it for more then 365 day tho does that matter?? thanks

Comment: @haze - Try to backup the `debug.keystore` file and than try to delete it again... (Try to close any program that may using this file - eclipse, AVD etc..)

Comment: sorry its still not leting me do anything with it. is there a way of delete it with eclipse shut down

Comment: @haze - What he is writing to you when you are trying to delete it?

Comment: i have added a link above. i have deleted the debug keystore and then i made a new project and still no luck

Comment: @haze - Ok. After you delete the `debug.keystore` try to create another project on a new workspace (alternatively you can delete your `.metadata` from your workspace - don't foreget to **backup** before doing that)