# Phonegap - Hello Cordova error

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I followed the first tutorial of Phonegap - getting started with Android. I wrote the example "HelloCordova" as showed [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android). But when I click "run as Android application" Eclipse displays `your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your applications`. No error is pointed! I can't understand where's the problem (my file matches the example)!

Problems:
Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 07/04/12 0.34
Location: Unknown
Type: Android Packaging Problem

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you need to delete your debug certificate.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the android manifest file for any errors. Even the manifest file must be free of errors. You may have overlooked it as it is the last third file. Check with that for errors.

Comment: 1. clean the project run again. Projects->clean
or
2. Check the package you are using now. If it is old i.e 2.1 or something like that may its deprecated.....update to around 3.0 above packages and see if it works

Answer (score 5):

This problem is not related with Phonegap ...
You should delete the debug file at "%USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore", so then eclipse will gerenate a new debug file