# Android apps in Eclipse run error

Tags: android, eclipse

I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong with my Eclipse IDE. I've been developing several apps and I updated my Android SDK and updated Eclipse and now I can't run any of my apps. Every app (including API Demos so its not just mine) won't run and Eclipse says "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application."

I can't find the cause of this error and my apps ran before and this just started. I thought updating the Android SDK would help, but this is still giving me this error on any app I try to run. Please help! What do I do? The only error I've seen is this:

```
[2012-06-21 13:37:19 - ddmlib] Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:421)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:837)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:805)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:765)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

Comment: check your build path for errors

Comment: Maybe Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties might work?

Comment: What does the "Problems" tab in Eclipse say?

Comment: Man, I had something similar happen. A few hours into it I completely uninstalled the SDK and Eclipse and reinstalled them both.

Comment: For those encountering the same issue, but could not apply the answers: in my case, I was using both Android Studio and Eclipse. When I closed Android Studio and restarted Eclipse, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the great suggestions, guys! But, I solved my issue. I reinstalled Eclipse, the Android SDK, and still had the problem. Turns out, my `debug.keystore` was expired and all I had to do was delete that file as described here: ["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins) I've been developing for several years, but, admittedly, I've had a couple system rebuilds here and there and just last week marked my `debug.keystore` being over a year old. Go figure....

Then, since I reinstalled Eclipse, I had this issue: http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-solve-must-override-superclass.html

I'm back up and running again.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Cleaning` your project.

Check on `build` automatically.

`Restart` Eclipse.

If none works, take a `backup` of all your projects and `reinstall` Eclipse and SDK. No other go.