# I don't remember my android debug.keystore password

Tags: android, android-keystore

How can i see my debug.keystore password? 
I entered my password 3 or 4 month ago and now i don't remember.

If it is impossible, how can i create new debug.keystore?

Answer (score 383):

Usually the `debug.keystore` password is just "**android**".

You can delete it and Eclipse will automatically generate a new one, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2196397/4230345).

Comment: okay i try delete keystore and clean my project. adt created a new keystore, well what is default alias name?

Comment: i tried your suggestion it gives me error;
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <aliasname> does not exist
java.lang.Exception: Alias <aliasname> does not exist
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doPrintEntry(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(Unknown Source)

Comment: can you paste the line you typed ?

Comment: Default alias is androiddebugkey

Comment: Welcome to the android developer experience

Answer (score 166):

**The Default Configuration of debug.keystore file:**

```
Keystore name: "debug.keystore"
Keystore password: "android"
Key alias: "androiddebugkey"
Key password: "android"
CN: "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"
```

**Where is this file located?**

For Windows users: `C:\Users\[username]\.android\debug.keystore`

For macOS users: `~/.android/debug.keystore`

You can get the SHA1 by using the following command:

```sh
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\[username]\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Note: The above answer has just information of Android Studio's default configuration to access the `debug.keystore` (debug certificate). You can make a custom certificate if you want to use your own password or configuration.

Comment: Just FYI there is typo in Window path. You need the backslash after [username] C:\Users\[username]\.android\debug.keystore

Answer (score 6):

If you are not certain that the password has been set before, try just empty password. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Again you can generate your google api key. Your .keystore file will be, 
In Eclipse, Windows -> preferences ->Android -> build ->default debug keystore path will be there. You just use that .keystore and generate your api key again by using this link:

http://lokeshatandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/obtaining-google-maps-api-key.html

Comment: Then you would need new oauth client id's.   Easier to keep using the same keystore.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was create signed key, I was able to observe this when i read the errors probbaly
https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android