# How to get user's gender and date of birth by using googleapi client in android?

Tags: android, google-api-client

Hello all i am using google sign-in integration in my android app and everything is working fine but actually i also want to get user date of birth and his gender now does google provide this, if google provides this then what should i define in scopes inside my googleapiclient builder.My code for getting default-sign-in information is given below please tell me where should i use above two scopes to fetch them from api.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Comment: no can you please tell me how can i do that if you know  please??

Comment: i am trying for the same, i got the gender but the birthday always returns null

Comment: how didi u got the gender i am getting null for Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)

Comment: Does this one answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33906880/5001016

Comment: my problem is solved already thanks for the comment anyways ??

Comment: @aman post the solution also