# how to retrieve email from gplus using android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to find the latest solution with *GoogleApiClient.Plus.API* (android) for getting the **email** for the **gplus profile**. In internet, stackoverflow, every  example found is obsolete and deprecated and of no use.

If it can be fetched only from Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API then is it a two step process to fetch half of info from Auth API and rest from Plus.API ??

Thanks in advance for answer.

Answer (score 0):

First I assume you have a button for google plus sign in

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
             Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
             startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
             break;
        }
}
```

At your `onActivityResult` you will catch sign in result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from and you can extract your user information there
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        //This line is your need
        String yourEmail = acct.getEmail();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No I dont want to use this GoogleSignInApi as I have to pull some other information from gplus api. So do you suggest to call both api one after another. I think there should be a way to get the email from Person or GPlus Profile apis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the email that is associated with the device, and probably with your app too:

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) { //If email matches the account associated with the device
        String possibleEmail = account.name;
        ...
    }
}
```

Let me know if this worked

Comment: I am trying to use as below m_GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(m_activity)
                    .enableAutoManage(m_activity, this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                    .build();

            m_GoogleApiClient.connect();

Answer (score 0):

After two days of struggle at last this post saved my life ..
[How to get profile like gender from google signin in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892546/how-can-i-get-profile-like-gender-from-google-signin-in-android)

But the apis are obsolete, did a bit of scratch head and could make it work.

create your google api client like this

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .build();

        m_GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(m_activity)
                .enableAutoManage(m_activity, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();
```

then on onActivityResult()

```
GoogleSignInResult result =   Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            fetchConnectedProfileInfo();
        } 

public void fetchConnectedProfileInfo()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "fetchConnectedProfileInfo");
    if (m_GoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Plus.API)) {
        Plus.PeopleApi.load(m_GoogleApiClient, "me").setResultCallback(this);
    }
}
```

Refer my github page for full code sample https://github.com/sandipsahoo2k2/social-login