# I am always getting handlesigninresult : false

Tags: android

I am trying to add google sign in to my android app. I have downloaded the google-services.json file from the google developers site. I am still not sure if this file is correct. 
The code I used is from the google developers site itself.

My log cat status is:

> handleSignInResult:false77445893

"77445893" is the hash code.

I have added runtime permission for GET_ACCOUNTS too.

This is my google-services.json file:

```
    {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "746238481207",
    "project_id": "civil-sprite-154007"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:746238481207:android:83984ccf8a4ecc15",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.george.project"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "746238481207-0q17pl680i93e9qgeco3rjp74knipmco.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.example.george.project",
            "certificate_hash": "887E55694DCD8DA81377DB2F37C6276E64199263"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "746238481207-jlitalqjls0f0nnfbk516bma7j76p0a2.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyAytEslbivEZYWoulznIIIGQr7UfyVkeX4"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

**This is my java code:**

package com.example.george.project;

/**
 * Created by George on 29-12-2016.
 */

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

import java.io.InputStream;


public class GPlusFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "GPlusFragent";
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private SignInButton signInButton;
    private Button signOutButton;
    private Button disconnectButton;
    private LinearLayout signOutView;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
// options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity() /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
                .build();


    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gplus, parent, false);

        signInButton = (SignInButton) v.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signOutButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_profile_pic);

        mStatusTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.user_default);
        imgProfilePic.setImageBitmap(ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(getContext(),icon, 200, 200, 200, false, false, false, false));
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }

        });


        signOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Status status) {
                                updateUI(false);
                            }
                        });
            }

        });

        return v;
    }





    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            /*if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                // Get account information
                String mFullName = acct.getDisplayName();
                String mEmail = acct.getEmail();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),mFullName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }*/

            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }


    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess() + result.hashCode());

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
            //Similarly you can get the email and photourl using acct.getEmail() and  acct.getPhotoUrl()

            if(acct.getPhotoUrl() != null)
                new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString());

            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }




    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        if (signedIn) {
            signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            signOutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.user_default);
            imgProfilePic.setImageBitmap(ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(getContext(),icon, 200, 200, 200, false, false, false, false));
            signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            signOutButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }

    }


    /**
     * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
     * */
    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... uri) {
            String url = uri[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            if (result != null) {


                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result,200,200, true);
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(getContext(),resized,250,200,200, false, false, false, false));

            }
        }
    }


}
```

*Please help me out.*

Thanks

Comment: Please add a relevant piece of code or at least the link to the the developer page (ideally both).

Comment: Do you follow this links?
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in If so - please, post both `build.gradle` files, `google-services.json` and your java code to sign-in. By the way, are you looking for information on this site? For example this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493965/android-google-sign-in-always-shows-handlesigninresultfalse

Comment: i have added the code above.