# Get google account information after login in my website with google sign in (Used satellizer lib for login)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, google-api, satellizer

I have used [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)  and **node server** for login in my website with google sing in.

I have successfully login and following data added in mongodb database.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57adec45a8fb51401c1ba843"),
    "displayName" : "xyz user",
    "picture" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xxxxxxx_xx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/photo.jpg?sz=200",
    "google" : "100379763204xxxxxxxxx", //user id
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now, I want to get other information from google account like Gender, Phone Number, Location etc...

So, How to get all information of login user from google account?

Comment: i think this has already been answered here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892546/how-can-i-get-profile-like-gender-from-google-signin-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Not all of that information is actually available.  It will also depend upon if the user has set the information to public or not.

If you use the [People: get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) method it will return a person resource [Resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource).  Assuming the user has this information public you should see the information you are after.  This method is part of the Google+ api so it will only work if the user has a Google+ account.

There is also the People API which tends to return similar information [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get).   I am not sure exactly were this information is coming from.   It appears to be related to a users Google account as opposed to the Google+ account.

Answer (score 1):

I finally success , there is my solution :

```
getGoogleDatas: function (id) {
    return $http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo", {
        params: {
            access_token: $auth.getToken(),
            alt: 'json'
        }
    });
}
```

and then :

```
getGoogleDatas().then(function (response) {
    user = response;
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error:', error);
});
```