# How get the gender and the birthdate of users using the Google Sign-In for Websites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, google-signin

I need to get the gender and birthdate of users using the Google Sign-In for Websites.

**The info I get from users**:

[image]

But I cant take the *birthdate and gender*

I used this guide for reference https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this I found by googling for google sign in gender https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892546/how-to-get-profile-like-gender-from-google-signin-in-android

Comment: is the same for javascript and android? because that link is for android

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/227

Comment: oooh thanks I'll try

Answer (score 1):

It took me a day figuring out this. Hope it will help others .

1. I am using **react-google-login**.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login
- https://dev.to/sivaneshs/add-google-login-to-your-react-apps-in-10-mins-4del

Adding scope in GoogleLogin:

```
<GoogleLogin
clientId = 'YOUR CLIENT ID'
buttonText = 'Login'
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
onSuccess = {handleSuccess}
onFailure = {handleFail}
cookiePolicy = {"single_host_origin"}
/>
```

2. In your JSON data you will get **googleId** and **accessToken**.
   [JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQnTt.png)
3. Then call get function passing these 2 values.
   You can either use **googleId** or you can use people/**me** and add a parameter **access_token** with the token data.

   ```
    axios
    .get(`https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/${googleId}?personFields=birthdays,genders&access_token=${accessToken}`)
    .then((response) => {console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4)); }) //You will get data here
    .catch((error) => {console.warn(JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));});
   ```

*Note : The birthday should be set public. https://aboutme.google.com/