# Getting User Gender From Google ApI

Tags: android, android-studio, google-plus

I have implemented the following...

```
private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {

    if (user != null) {
        name=user.getDisplayName();
        email=user.getEmail();
        phone=user.getPhoneNumber();

    } else {
        name=" ";
        email=" ";
        phone=" ";
    }
}
```

This is used to get basic information such as email, name, and phone number. I cannot find a .getGender and was wondering if the google API has another way for me to access it. So far, I have the following permissions.

```
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892546/how-to-get-profile-like-gender-from-google-signin-in-android