# What scope I have to use to access gender of user while using Google Sign In

Tags: android, google-signin

I am able to access birthday, name etc but there is no scope for gender so it always returns null,

Please tell me how can i access Gender of user

Question [How to get profile like gender from google signin in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892546/how-to-get-profile-like-gender-from-google-signin-in-android)

In this question already told about how to get user information and it is working but not in case of gender because there is no scope available to ask for permission of gender

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get profile like gender from google signin in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892546/how-to-get-profile-like-gender-from-google-signin-in-android)

Comment: In that question already told about how to get user information and it is working but not in case of gender because there is no scope available to ask for permission of gender

Answer (score 1):

I kind of find the  solution for problem.

I tried to make gender public in my account then I became able to get it.

But now I need to know how I can get gender when it is private.