# forget where I left my key Android Studio

Tags: java, android, key, keystore

Sorry if my English is not good, the question is:
I've compiled my application for android and is currently in Google Play, today I tried to update it but forget that folder left my key, look for hours and not find there any way to know from Android Studio with that key was compiled the application or failing that, a tool that helps that information?
regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you lost debug.keystore file ???

first check is this file available of not,
click this link to know where this file is stored 
[Android Studio - debug keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622528/android-studio-debug-keystore)

if you lost this file, here is the link someone answered for 
[I lost my .keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file)