# Location of debug keystore in Android Studio, does it exist?

Tags: android-studio, keystore

After a lay off, I migrated my Android development from Eclipse under Windows to a new machine with Android Studio running under Ubuntu.

Because I wished to port an existing project using Google Maps v1 (which no longer issues new API keys) I copied the release and debug keystores to the new machine.

Under Eclipse there was no need to know the location of the debug keystore which was created automatically and debug loads signed with it.

Under Android Studio, does the same principle apply? If there is a system created debug keystore, where is it, or do I have to define one explicitly?

Comment: Look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-the-debug-keystore-in-android-studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-the-debug-keystore-in-android-studio) and here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622528/android-studio-debug-keystore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622528/android-studio-debug-keystore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described here in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

You can find the debug keystore in `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore`

Comment: Thank you, it's in the same place as for Eclipse. I don't know why I didn't think of looking there. Edit: Oh yes I do know why - I put Eclipse on first and must have assumed that it was solely for Eclipse's use

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a debug.keystore file is created for you by Android Studio. It is in your user home directory under `.android/debug.keystore` (i.e., on Linux/Mac at `~/.android/debug.keystore`