# Android Studio AndroidDebugKey

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the location and path of the AndroidDebugKey used by the gradle build.

By default it points to $HOME./android/debug.keystore. What is the process in Android Studio (2.3.1) to change it another location.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated question : [look at 3rd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622528/android-studio-debug-keystore/28795257#28795257).
This is a copy/paste from previous link.

You can specify your own debug keystore if you wish.  This solution also gives you the ability to store your keys outside of the project directory as well as enjoy automation in the signing process. Yes you can go to `File -> Project Structure` and assign signing keystores and passwords in the `Signing` tab but that will put plaintext entries into your gradle.build file which means your secrets might be disclosed (especially in repository commits).  With this solution you get the control of using your own keystore and the magic of automation during debug and release builds.

**1)** **Create a gradle.properties (if you don't already have one).**

The location for this file depends on your OS:

```
   /home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
   /Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
   C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

**2) Add an entry pointing to `yourprojectname.properties` file.**
 (example for Windows)

```
yourprojectname.properties=c:\\Users\\<username>\\signing\\yourprojectname.properties
```

**3) Create `yourprojectname.properties` file in the location you specified in Step 2 with the following information:**

```
keystore=C:\\path\\to\\keystore\\yourapps.keystore
keystore.password=your_secret_password
```

**4) Modify your `gradle.build` file to point to `yourprojectname.properties` file to use the variables.**

```
if(project.hasProperty("yourprojectname.properties")
        && new File(project.property("yourprojectname.properties")).exists()) {

    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("yourprojectname.properties"))))

    android {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias 'release'
                keyPassword props['keystore.password']
                storeFile file(props['keystore'])
                storePassword props['keystore.password']
            }
            debug {
                keyAlias 'debug'
                keyPassword props['keystore.password']
                storeFile file(props['keystore'])
                storePassword props['keystore.password']
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "your.project.app"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 17
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

**5) Enjoy!**  Now all of your keys will be outside of the root of the directory and yet you still have the joys of automation for each build.

If you get an error in your gradle.build file about the "props" variable it's because you are not executing the "android {}" block inside the very first `if` condition where the `props` variable gets assigned so just move the entire android{ ... } section into the condition in which the props variable is assigned then try again.

I pieced these steps together from the information found [here](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/) and [here](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/).

Comment: I was looking for how you do it via the Android Studio IDE. When you generate a release APK, you get a wizard that allows you to choose a key. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/generating-an-apk-in-the-debug-mode.html indicates it is possible in Intellij and in Android Studio under Project Structure/Modules/Signing or Build Types it appears you can do something similar but it does not seem to work