# Where is debug.keystore in Android Studio

Tags: android, keystore, android-studio

I need to enable google+ api, so I need the `debug.keystore`. I switched to Android Studio and do not know where it is. I can find it in eclipse at path ~/.android/debug.keystore.

Comment: I would assume that Android Studio uses the same debug keystore. That one is not tied to Eclipse -- Ant uses it as well.

Comment: Did you build or run the project on a device? It won't be there unless you've built an apk atleast once.

Comment: Build for debug or production?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622528/android-studio-debug-keystore. Useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189076/what-is-the-equivalent-of-eclipse-custom-debug-keystore-in-android-studio

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456491/i-dont-remember-my-android-debug-keystore-password

Answer (score 174, accepted):

**EDIT**
Step 1) Go to File > Project Structure > select project > go to "signing" and select your default or any keystore you want and fill all the details. In case you are not able to fill the details, hit the green '+' button. I've highlighted in the screenshot.[image]

Step 2) VERY IMPORTANT: Goto Build Types> select your build type and select your "Signing Config". In my case, I've to select "config". Check the highlighted region.
[image]

Comment: I can't see "Facets" written anywhere in Project Structure.

Comment: Which Studio are you using? If it is Studio 0.3.2 or above, then I am with you on this one!

Comment: bummer! I'll explore it in a while. Doing a big project and don't want to upgrade and mess my IDE settings! Meanwhile, can you please update it to us if you find it?

Comment: I just ran the hello world project once on Android Studio, and it appeared at ~/.android/

Comment: @Vera You might want to to mention that the key alias is likely to be 'androiddebugkey' (this is the default), not 'android'.

Comment: I hope people already know about the alias naming. I just posted sample :) Thanks!

Comment: where can i find the store file :debug.keystore. in my system both eclipse and android studio installed now am work with studio.no one is giving correct process from couple of days am seraching for google places api integration process for development and  please any one help me.

Comment: Harsha - In my system my debug.keystore is at this location (you should be able to figure yours out from this). Mine is Windows 7: C:\Users\homepc\.android

Comment: but no keystore path displayed here every field is empty

Comment: Hello @Harsha, please give a screenshot of what you get. try to click that green '+' button and click the '...' button to look for keystore.

Comment: You can make your project compatible among multiple users by editing the signing configs section in the build.gradle file, and changing storeFile as follows: `storeFile file("$System.env.USERPROFILE" + '/.android/debug.keystore')`

Comment: Worked for me.  I had to set 'Signing config' to 'config' for both debug & release.  Now I can use the same Google API keys for debug & release.  Makes things a bit easier.

Comment: Thx Prachi.  I was having logging in issues using Google Drive API and it turned out to be a signing issue solved by combining your answer here and that of alexshr below.

Comment: Works, I accidentally deleted or changed my config files so the IDE was looking for the keystore in the default folder (C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore). I made the changes in the Project Structure and my app is running.

Comment: This variable can be used in signing config filed: $signingConfigs.debug to sign with debug key.

Answer (score 156):

- For Windows User:  `C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore`
  (Replace USERNAME with your actual PC user name)
- For Linux or Mac OS User:  `~/.android/debug.keystore`

After you will get `SHA1` by below Code using Command Prompt:

```
  keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: You can also specify the path like this `"$HOME\.android\debug.keystore"`

Answer (score 73):

In Android Studio you can find all your app signing information without any console command:

1. Open your project
2. Click on Gradle from right side panel
3. In Gradle projects panel open folders: Your **Project -> Tasks-> Android**
4. Run signingReport task (double click) and you will see the result in Gradle console (keystore paths,SHA1,MD5 and so on).

[image: signingReport task and its result]

Comment: i am looking for release key store. Variant: release, config: none. but I already set up release key. please help.

Comment: Thx alexshr.  I was having logging in issues using Google Drive API and it turned out to be a signing issue solved by combining your answer here and that of Prachi above.

Comment: +1 Apart from generating SHA1 etc. it also tells the path/location of debug keystore being used for that project.

Comment: this is the best! accepted answer does not work when default values are used (i.e. debug keystore was not specified in my case). turned out `.android` folder in my android SDK was being used..

Answer (score 61):

You can use this command and will fetch all your key-stores, go to your terminal and in your android root directory run this:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

it will give you something like this a list of key-store and their information:

[image]

Answer (score 59):

Another way of finding out your key information is to go to your java folder, for me it was at

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
```

and run the following command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

*from the command you can easily see that  keystore address is "c:\users/<%mylogin%>.android\debug.keystore" , alias is "androiddebugkey"  store password is "android"  key password is "android"*

This is the default configuration from the Android 'Get API Key' documentation.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Comment: If you are using a new version of Android Studio(my version is 2.2.2), you can find keytool in "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin".

Answer (score 28):

I got this problem. The `debug.keystore` file was missing.
So the only step that created a correct file for me was **creating a new Android project in Android Studio.**

It created me a new `debug.keystore` under path `C:\Users\username\.android\`.

This solution probably works only when you have not created any projects yet.

Comment: I accidently deleted my debug.keystore file. This post helped me to regenerate that file.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I am surprised Android Studio does not create one when it's installed....

Answer (score 25):

It helped me.

**Keystore name:** "debug.keystore"
**Keystore password:** "android"
**Key alias:** "androiddebugkey"
**Key password:** "android"

[image: exapmle]

USER_NAME_PC - Your PC username

Comment: Caution to reader: The text for `Key alias` is correct (`androiddebugkey`) but the screenshot is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

If you find that you do not have JDK installed.  Go to your android terminal and navigate to the bin folder of JRE that comes with Android Studio.

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
```

and run the following command. Remember to replace USERNAME with your actual PC username.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 4):

From the Android Developers documentation about [Signing your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#expdebug) :

> #### Expiry of the debug certificate
>
> [...] The file is stored in the following locations:
>
> - `~/.android/` on OS X and Linux
> - `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\` on Windows XP
> - `C:\Users\<user>\.android\` on Windows Vista and Windows 7, 8, and 10

Answer (score 2):

On Windows,

All you need to do is goto command prompt and `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin>`where `jdk-10.0.2 or full path` can be different in your case. once you are in the bin, enter this code `keytool -keystore C:\Users\GB\.android/debug.keystore -list -v` where `C:\Users\GB\.android/debug.keystore` is path to keystore in my case.

You will get results like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Android Studio's SDK was installed in this location:

`E:\Android\AppData\Local\Sdk`

And my `.android` file was in:

`%UserProfile%\.android`

To set up the environment variables correctly, follow these steps:

1. Remove the `ANDROID_HOME` or `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` variable from the environment variables.
2. Create a new variable with the name `ANDROID_HOME` and the value of your SDK location (e.g., `E:\Android\AppData\Local\Sdk`).
3. Create a new variable with the name `ANDROID_USER_HOME` and the value of the directory where your `.android` file is located (e.g., `%UserProfile%\.android`).
4. Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, if the debug.keystore file is not in the location (C:\Users\username\.android), the debug.keystore file may also be found in the location where you have installed Android Studio.

Comment: The only right answer for someone who installed android studio outsude C drive

Answer (score 1):

The default keystore file: `debug.keystore` is present in the folder `.android` which is usually located in the default home folder of your operating system of the user who installed that Android SDK.

In my Ubuntu PC, it's location is `/home/dhananjay/.android`

Whereas in the Windows PC it is located at `C:\Users\dhananjay\.android`

Answer (score 1):

**=======================================**

**in standart File Explorer:**

**=======================================**

[image: in standart File Explorer:]

**=======================================**

**open View tab and check Hidden items  :**

**=======================================**

[image: open view tab and check Hidden]

**=======================================**

**Now you can see your .android folder**

**=======================================**

[image: Now you can see your .android folder]

Answer (score 1):

**[SOLVED] How I made my app run again after I had changed my username on same Windows 10 machine**

In Android Studio, File > Project Structure > app > clicked “+” to add new configuration "config"
[File > Project Structure > app > Signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke5A0.png)

[image]

In Flavors tab > Signing box, chose new "config" entry
[File > Project Structure > app > Flavors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4eh1.png)

[image]

This reconfigured the app. Closed & restarted Studio

Clicked Build > Rebuild Project

The app added and showed this automatically:
[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVLbc.png)
[image]

When I tested the app on a cell phone, Studio asked to reinstall the app with this new configuration. App runs as before!

DynaMike

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is specified in the app/build.gradle file. For example:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file(System.env.HOME + '/.android/debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing I can think of is to grab the fingerprint from the debug.keystore (paths are mentioned in other answers) and add that to your project.  No need to copy keystores or add new apps.  Just append to the list of fingerprints for each machine you develop on.

FWIW, I ran into this when I switched from one laptop to another.  I bounce around a lot.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000104?hl=en#sha1

Hope that helps some folks out! :)

Answer (score 0):

`Go to Build > Clean Project`

Build your project again.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Flutter you have to open the android part of the project only
File->open->select the android folder of that project
wait few minutes to complete the gradle sync after that on the right side click on the gradle->android->Tasks->android->signin Report

Answer (score 0):

I needed the debug.keystore after I had just installed Android Studio, and it was not in the .android folder.

My solution was to create a new empty project, **Build->Select Build Varient...** then under **Active Build Varient** I set it to **debug**. I then **built the project**, and I **even ran debug** on it too (not sure if nessisary). After this I checked in the .android folder, and debug.keystore was generated.

Answer (score -1):

try to sync the gradle before .
the complete the steps in tasks ...