# What is the equivalent of Eclipse "Custom debug Keystore" in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

As I am working with Google Maps API, I have been used to work with a custom debug key in Eclipse (that is in fact my production key)

This manipulation allowed me to use the same API key for Maps and most of Google Play Services (in app billing) in my debug and release build.

This was really convenient because there was no need to change the key in the manifest.

[image]

Unfortunately, with the migration to Android Studio, I am missing this feature.

Any idea where I can find this option back?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You define a keystore in your build.gradle file. See the Signing Configurations section here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

In your case, you want to redefine the keystore for the debug variant:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("your.keystore")
        }
    }
}
```

However, you should really be using two different keystores for debug and release configurations.

Comment: Thank a lot, I will try that. Why should I use different keys? The result and the amount of time I gained is huge...

Comment: Is there any constraint regarding the debug keystore's password?

Comment: What if I want one specific keystore for each flavor in debug?

Comment: @Waza_Be Release keystore and passwords need to be closely guarded. Debug keystore is more of a convenience. If someone gets a hold of your release keystore (and password, or they could possibly brute force the password) they can generate apks that install on top of ones you have published (ex: including malware). If they also have your play store login they could publish their own update to the play store. With your maps api key, they could make many requests to the maps api and use up your quota, possibly end up charging you money, and take down maps functionality in your production app.

Answer (score 26):

On recent Android Studio 0.8.9 you will find this at a way better place:

```
 File->Project Structure
```

1. Add a keystore at "Signing" Tab
2. Select it for your debug/release "Build types".
3. Make sure the alias name matchs with your keystore (keytool -list -v shows your alias name)

It creates the gradle stuff, syncrhonizes automatically on "Apply" and worked immediately like a charm.

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify all the fields. For a debug key, you can omit the defaults (alias 'androidebugkey' and keystore/key password set to 'android'). For a release key, you may not want to enter your password there as it will be stored in clear in the build.gradle which then ends on up on your DVCS.

Answer (score 18):

Hi If you don't want to go for hard code all of this stuff , then go for below easy steps

```
->Your project
  ->Your Module
  ->Right click on your module
   ->go to open module settings
      ->Go to Signing section
         ->Specify all the attribute here and browse your Custom debug key in Store File
```

Then you will find below code which will be auto-create by android studio in build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('custom_debug_keystore')
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
        storePassword 'android'
    }
}
```

Note:

1) Please do not use .keystore in the code manually you go for manual configuration

2) Please specify correct Alias and password

Answer (score 9):

Here is a complete step-by-step that I took to move both of my keys out of the gradle.build file into a file that will not be included in any builds or repository commits.

**1)** **Create a gradle.properties (if you don't already have one).**

The location for this file depends on your OS:

```
   /home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
   /Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
   C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

**2) Add an entry pointing to `yourprojectname.properties` file.**
 (example for Windows)

```
yourprojectname.properties=c:\\Users\\<username>\\signing\\yourprojectname.properties
```

**3) Create `yourprojectname.properties` file in the location you specified in Step 2 with the following information:**

```
keystore=C:\\path\\to\\keystore\\yourapps.keystore
keystore.password=your_secret_password
```

**4) Modify your `gradle.build` file to point to `yourprojectname.properties` file to use the variables.**

```
if(project.hasProperty("yourprojectname.properties")
        && new File(project.property("yourprojectname.properties")).exists()) {

    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("yourprojectname.properties"))))

    android {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias 'release'
                keyPassword props['keystore.password']
                storeFile file(props['keystore'])
                storePassword props['keystore.password']
            }
            debug {
                keyAlias 'debug'
                keyPassword props['keystore.password']
                storeFile file(props['keystore'])
                storePassword props['keystore.password']
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "your.project.app"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 17
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

**5) Enjoy!**  Now all of your keys will be outside of the root of the directory and yet you still have the joys of automation for each build.

If you get an error in your gradle.build file about the "props" variable it's because you are not executing the "android {}" block inside the very first `if` condition where the `props` variable gets assigned so just move the entire android{ ... } section into the condition in which the props variable is assigned then try again.

I pieced these steps together from the information found [here](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/) and [here](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/).

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the `debug.keystore` for ***your project*** **independently**.
Two steps with the following images: (Android Studio **v0.5.2**)
**Step 1**: Click the button of `project structure`.
[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**: Add the `debug.keystore` as follows.
[image]

Comment: Hope in Android Studio v0.8 this screen not available. Only way may be build.gradle, correct me if im wrong pls.

Answer (score 4):

The keystore needs to be in build.gradle, example follows:

```
android{
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('/path/platform.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
       }
    }
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

**Eclipse didn't really ask for a password or alias, but gradle does.** I believe Eclipse just assumed it was password:*android* and alias:*androiddebugkey*. This might not be true for your keystore but I would try it like that on gradle.

**If you know the password, but you are not sure of the alias** you can also run the following command to get the alias:
`keytool -list -keystore /path/platform.keystore` [link](http://vancelucas.com/blog/listing-aliases-inside-an-android-keystore-file-with-keytool/)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you can use the gradle file to specify it.
I also found very convenient to use the Home folder as part of the path. It makes it easier when working within a team. Here is my suggestion :

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file(System.properties['user.home']+"/.android/custom.debug.keystore")
        }
    }
}
```