# How to generate same signature for apk from multiple sdk on debug mode?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk, apktool

I have developed app and distributed as a private app not from play store and we are generated apk in Debug Mode.

The problem here is we are delivering an app from different system means different developers so it's generating different signature then try to install new version it's giving like "APP not installed an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed".

I want to be generate same signature from different SDK. Other wise suggest me way distributing an application but not from play store.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same debug keystore and store it in your repository.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924901/using-the-same-debug-keystore-on-multiple-computers) you can find how to configure debugkeystore in eclipse. And [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189076/what-is-the-equivalent-of-eclipse-custom-debug-keystore-in-android-studio) how to configure it in android studio. You can use existing debug keystore file or [generate a new one.](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/scaleform-mobile-development/getting-an-android-debug-keystore/td-p/4261689)