# How can I sign testing apk in Android Studio?

Tags: android, testing, apk

I am developing an app in such an android device that requires each app to be signed with a specific key, even the testing apk.

I know how to sign an app by configuring build.gradle. But signing testing app (Instrumentation test) seems no such configing, am I missing something ?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189076/what-is-the-equivalent-of-eclipse-custom-debug-keystore-in-android-studio

Answer (score 3):

try this in build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyPassword 'your pw'
        storeFile file('your keystore file path')
        storePassword 'your pw'
        keyAlias 'your alias'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for NateZh and TWL.

Yes, the answer is to add flowing lines to `build.gradle`:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        keyPassword 'your pw'
        storeFile file('your keystore file path')
        storePassword 'your pw'
        keyAlias 'your alias'
    }
}
```

But, there are more to be take care of:

1. When using `signingConfigs.debug`, this tells gradle it's debug key, no need to specific  `buildTypes.debug.signingConfig` again
2. `SigingConfigs.debug` also take effect when building instrumentation test
3. In multi-modules project, if you want to test a module, you should include `signingConfigs.debug` in the module's `build.gradle`.

For example, my project looks like:

```
app
    -build.gradle
libs
    -src/androidTest/java/com/my/MyTest.java
    -build.gradle
```

Adding `signingConfigs.debug` to app has no effect when I want to run libs' `AndroidDebugTest`. Instead, adding `signingConfigs.debug` to libs' `build.gradle` do the work.

Hope it's helpful to others.

Comment: If you want to use a different signingConfig for your debug build you can still specify buildTypes.signingConfig with your own configuration, but for the instrumenation test apk the android.signingConfigs.debug is used.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you! I just can't believe that the module is also needed to be signed to make the instrumentation test working.