# Truecaller sdk implementation getting trueError.getErrorType() 3 and can't delete previous ADD APP from developer.truecaller.com

Tags: android

Implement TrueCaller SDK in my app but  returns the 'trueError.getErrorType() 3' 'onFailureProfileShared()'. I have also add

```
@Override
public void onSuccesProfileShared(@NonNull final TrueProfile trueProfile) {
    final String fullName = trueProfile.firstName + " " + trueProfile.lastName;
    mProfileName.setText(fullName);
    mProfilePhone.setText(trueProfile.phoneNumber);
    mProfileEmail.setText(trueProfile.email);
    mProfileAddress.setText(trueProfile.city);
    final List<String> jobComponents = new ArrayList<>(2);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(trueProfile.jobTitle)) {
        jobComponents.add(trueProfile.jobTitle);
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(trueProfile.companyName)) {
        jobComponents.add(trueProfile.companyName);
    }
    mProfileJob.setText(TextUtils.join(" @ ", jobComponents));

    if (mTruecallerRequestNonce.equals(trueProfile.requestNonce)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The request nonce matches", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailureProfileShared(@NonNull final TrueError trueError) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed sharing - Reason: " + trueError.getErrorType(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

android:value="YOUR_PARTNER_KEY_HERE"/>

my app AndroidManifest.xml.

AND also unable to delete or edit previous App credential from https://developer.truecaller.com/dashboard/applications , documentation not provide in truecaller developer site.

Comment: Got the answer?

Comment: yes @PrakhaRaM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369186/truecaller-android-sdk-error-code-3/45978735#45978735