# TrueCaller Android SDK ERROR_TYPE_UNAUTHORIZED_PARTNER

Tags: java, android, authentication, sdk

I am trying to implement Truecaller Verification in my app but I continuously getting Error code 3 for 2 days I tried 3 types of SHA1 keys 1) Debug 2) Release 3)keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name} none of them worked for me also I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369186/truecaller-android-sdk-error-code-3) but couldn't solve my issue can someone please tell me how to solve it?

MY CODE:
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button verifyUser;
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        verifyUser = findViewById(R.id.VerifyUser);

        verifyUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getUserDetails();
            }
        });
        TruecallerSdkScope trueScope = new TruecallerSdkScope.Builder(this, sdkCallback)
                .consentMode(TruecallerSdkScope.CONSENT_MODE_BOTTOMSHEET)
                .buttonColor(Color.parseColor("#454545"))
                .buttonTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
                .loginTextPrefix(TruecallerSdkScope.LOGIN_TEXT_PREFIX_TO_GET_STARTED)
                .loginTextSuffix(TruecallerSdkScope.LOGIN_TEXT_SUFFIX_PLEASE_VERIFY_MOBILE_NO)
                .ctaTextPrefix(TruecallerSdkScope.CTA_TEXT_PREFIX_USE)
                .buttonShapeOptions(TruecallerSdkScope.BUTTON_SHAPE_ROUNDED)
                .privacyPolicyUrl("<<YOUR_PRIVACY_POLICY_LINK>>")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("<<YOUR_PRIVACY_POLICY_LINK>>")
                .footerType(TruecallerSdkScope.FOOTER_TYPE_ANOTHER_METHOD)
                .consentTitleOption(TruecallerSdkScope.SDK_CONSENT_TITLE_VERIFY)
                .sdkOptions(TruecallerSdkScope.SDK_OPTION_WITHOUT_OTP)
                .build();
        TruecallerSDK.init(trueScope);


    }
    private final ITrueCallback sdkCallback = new ITrueCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccessProfileShared(@NonNull final TrueProfile trueProfile) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailureProfileShared(@NonNull final TrueError trueError) {
            Log.d("checksdk" , "error" + trueError.getErrorType());
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationRequired(@Nullable final TrueError trueError) {
        }

    };

    public void getUserDetails(){
        if(TruecallerSDK.getInstance().isUsable()){
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            TruecallerSDK.getInstance().setLocale(locale);
            TruecallerSDK.getInstance().getUserProfile(MainActivity.this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == TruecallerSDK.SHARE_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            TruecallerSDK.getInstance().onActivityResultObtained(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.truecaller.android.sdk"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LoginOtp"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <meta-data android:name="com.truecaller.android.sdk.PartnerKey" android:value="@string/partnerKey"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```