# Where is the key that Android Studio signs development builds with?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I click the *Run* button in Android Studio, it installs and runs the app on the device.

If I carry the device to a different machine, where I check out the same app and click run, it will tell me that this build is signed with a different key, so the app first has to be uninstalled, which takes time and deletes the app's data.

I would like to use the same key on both machines, so that I can switch between them.

Where do I find that key, or even better, is its location configurable?

Comment: by key you mean the `keystore` or the `signing key` ?

Comment: @inkredusk What's the difference?

Comment: The `private signing key` is the encrypted private key created automatically required to enroll existing apps to App Signing by Google Play. It is only used when you have already published an app to the Play Store and need to transfer your private key to Google so they can sign the APKs with the same key as your previous versions. Where as the `keystore` is something that you create and you can reuse the same on multiple machines.

Comment: @inkredusk I still don't get your question. Isn't the key always in a keystore? if yes, then I just want to know where that keystore is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of Eclipse "Custom debug Keystore" in Android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189076/what-is-the-equivalent-of-eclipse-custom-debug-keystore-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug.keystore file is located in the following paths:

- Linux and MacOS: `~/.android/debug.keystore`
- Windows: `C:\Users\%username%\.android\debug.keystore`

If you want to change debug.keystore to your keystore, then add the following code to your app level build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("path/to/your/debug.keystore")
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

If you need to sign a release build, then add the following code:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("path/to/your/release.keystore")
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This answers my question. About the custom path: Is it possible to set this in a *local* config? The app level `build.gradle` is usually checked in.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, and you don't want to set up `build.gradle` in each new project, then the easiest way is to copy `debug.keystore` from the `.android` path, and transfer it with replacement along this path on another machine.

Answer (score -1):

For development build you could just build the .apk file without any key. But if you are referring to signing key need by Google Play to upload the apps, you could create it in Android Studio.

Please make sure, you select .apk file for development build(not bundle) if you intend to just test it on your device.

Comment: I'm talking about the key that Android Studio apparently uses automatically when I click the *Run* button. If it would build without any key, I should be able to build and install the app from another machine without uninstalling first.