# Google+ login error "An internal error occured"

Tags: android, google-plus

I have integrated google+ login to android app and it has been working fine. But from today whenever I try to login it returns an error "An internal error occured."

Only logs I see is : `who=null, result=null, requestCode=9000`.

I am using Google Maps without any problem so this is not due to wrong key on Google console.

Comment: Try sync-ing your google account!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why Google Maps was working and Google+ sign in not. But recreating an android app key in [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) worked. *Remember, when you create a new app key in console you have to replace it with older one in your code wherever you use.*

Comment: I have Google Maps working, but Google+ Sign isn't. I tried that but didn't work. I generated the new key, updated the app with it, but no result. I even cleaned the project, restarted Eclipse and deleted the APK from the device (with no result). I'll try to find an answer tomorrow and make another comment if I succeed (and remember to come back here).

Comment: @gian1200 did you succeed? i'm also failing at the same point!

Comment: @AkashRamani I did. However, I don't remember exactly what I did. But if my memory doesn't fail me, what I did was to create an OAuth Client ID in the Google Console or do the link process through the Android Developer instead of the Google Console. Remember that the Google Console and the Android Console are 2 separated consoles and need to be linked in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to always have the latest API key which was generated by using the SHA1 certificate of your current certificate that you are using to sign the application. This problem may have occurred if you reinstalled the sdk or the OS or created a new signing key.

Comment: The strange part is that Google Maps was working which uses the same key and Google+ login was not working. Moreover, I did not reinstalled SDK nor OS nor created new signing key.

Comment: Strange. Could be a bug in the API console.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set your SHA1 fingerprint (debug or release) in your google developer console and you still having this problem, check if you effectively build with your key, here is the way to set the key in Android Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17992232/2486332

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.