# Internal Error by start from IDE

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I develop a android app with visual studio 2012 and xamarin. I worke in a team with different machines. I start my android app on a nexus 4 device and everythink works. When I start my android app from a other machine, I get an internal error:

Deployment failed because of an internal error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
   bei Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
   bei Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c_*DisplayClass2a.b*_29(Task`1 t)
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunLogged(CancellationToken token)
   bei Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.Start(CancellationToken token)

I have deinstalled the app on my device, I deinstalled it with adb shell. Why I get this internal error. Any ideas? Have I to change my manifest?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="net.package.name" android:installLocation="auto"  android:versionName="1.9" android:versionCode="10">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application android:debuggable="true" android:label="name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem related to ADB and not the code. As @ozwislon suggested you can have to **uninstall manually the app** when you want to install one from an other machine.

That's because of the android `debug.keystore` which is used to sign any debug application. To avoid that install/uninstall annoying issue in my team we are using the same `debug.keystore` which is located in  `C:\Users\your_username_here\.android`

Comment: I don't find debug.keystore, i also try to avoid this annoying issue

Comment: It is usually located under user profile. Or this is your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-the-debug-keystore-in-android-studio

Comment: Thanx for answer, i'm using Xamarin, maybe in my case it should be in a file called adbkey or adbkey.pub ?

Comment: it must end in `.keystore`

Comment: I don't find it in .android folder :(

Comment: Look in : C:\Users\{YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. All I had to do was go into the Settings | Applications menu and remove the application there first. For some reason the VS/Xamarin addon wasn't removing the app properly from the device. Even manually using the ADB shell didn't remove it properly for me.

If this doesn't work for you, there's a bunch of other things you can try here, on the Xamarin forums:

[Xamarin Deployment failed because of an internal error](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3010/deployment-failed-because-of-an-internal-error-failure-install-failed-update-incompatible)