# GoogleSignInResult isSuccess failed

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I want to use the Google Login for my App, but I always get the message `Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12500, resolution=null` and the login failed. Has anyone an idea what the problem is?

Here is my Activity:

```
public class GruppenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private LernAppDB db;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gruppen);

        // Views
        mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        db = new LernAppDB(this);
        sqlDatabase = db.getReadableDatabase();


        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this , this )
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {

            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
            ZentraleDB zentraleDB = new ZentraleDB();
            ZentraleDB.benutzerAnlegen(sqlDatabase,personEmail,"hans","wilhelm",personName,"tesr");
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        if (signedIn) {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                signOut();
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                revokeAccess();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check what value you are using for R.string.server_client_id ... it should be a OAuth *web* server client ID registered for your project in the Google Developers Console, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34591949/5001016

Comment: The value is the OAuth web server client ID. This is not the solution :(

Comment: Check that you registered all the package names / SHA-1 hashes that you use? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html

Comment: I've registered alle package names and the SHA-1 hash is correct. Could you please look via teamviewer (you can get the ID and password on facebbok) on my code and on my google access?

Answer (score 9):

Few things to check:

**1.** Check your correct **SHA certificate fingerprints** in [Firebase Console.](https://console.firebase.google.com)

**2.** Check below warning in [Google API Console.](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID)

[image]

- If you see that error, You need to choose **Support email** in **OAuth consent screen** tab like an example below.

[image]

After chosen a support email, the warning disappeared. and it started working.

Answer (score 8):

We had same problem **Error 12500**, nothing help... Code was ok, SHA-1 keys ok, checked a lot of times... 
Spend two days with this f**king issue...

But we didn't have accepted **OAuth consent** on page https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=[PROJECT_ID]
That help, just accept and fill page with OAuth consent, and it start working without any issue after.

Answer (score 3):

I was using Google plus login successfully but faced same problem after changing the laptop I used for developing the app earlier.
Reason was change in SHA-1 registered on Google Developer Console.
So I'd recommend re-iterating the [integration guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#prerequisites) and fixing google-services.json (Configuration file) located in your app folder. Because problem could be with your in API keys, APIs enabled or the SHA-1.

Comment: yes, after changing computer you must recreate SHA-1: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Answer (score 2):

Calling the connect() function after the "sing-in" code worked for me.

```
     Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(sActivity.mGoogleApiClient);
    sActivity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    mGoogleApiClient.connect(); //Adding this worked for me!
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the Signing Certificate and the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint. Add the following SHA-1 certificates into your googleApi credentials. there are 2 cases

1.If you are running in debug mode add the SHA-1 fingerprint generated by the following

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\keytool" -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

2.If you have configured `Signing Config` then use SHA-1 fingerprint generated by following

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\keytool" -list -v -keystore "[youKeyPath]\youKey.jks"
```

I recommend you to add both the SHA-1 fingerprints in your googleApi credentials

Answer (score 0):

[https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in ] follow this api documentation but keep in mind that inside WEB_CLIENT_ID use the value of client id which is generated inside google-services.json file.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private val TAG = "JSAGoogleSignIn"
private val REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 1234
//  private val WEB_CLIENT_ID = "969826080188-rs95o2iilt1l9u6g1su0hf271ml4d5bj.apps.googleusercontent.com"
private val WEB_CLIENT_ID = "354298333018-hh9bnkfuf0meimf2n2u0pio7dh8mg273.apps.googleusercontent.com"
private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

private var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var txt_register = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_register)
    txt_register.setOnClickListener {
        var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, RegisterActivity::class.java)
        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(WEB_CLIENT_ID)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
    mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build()

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    sign_in_button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
    }

}


override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}


private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
    if (user != null) {
        Log.e("Email", "Value" + user.email)
    }

}

fun signIn() {

}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val currentUser = mAuth!!.currentUser
    updateUI(currentUser)
}

public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {
        val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
        if (result.isSuccess) {
            // successful -> authenticate with Firebase
            val account = result.signInAccount
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account!!)
        } else {
            // failed -> update UI
            updateUI(null)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "SignIn: failed!" + result.status,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    Log.e(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle():" + acct.id!!)

    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.idToken, null)
    mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success
                    Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential: Success!")
                    val user = mAuth!!.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    // Sign in fails
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential: Failed!", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Authentication failed!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run a great example for testing Google Sign-In (https://github.com/thatfiredev/FirebaseAuthOneTapUI)
Here is the article by the author of the code - https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firebase-auth-one-tap-86ca80a80973

Error 12500 also occurred.
It was only necessary to add a Sign-in providers to the FireBase Console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JqqC.png)
And it worked!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30754033)