# GoogleSignInResult#isSuccess() returns false everytime

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, google-signin

I am trying to enable [google signin in my android app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) following [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/google-login-android-tutorial-integrate-gplus-login/) tutorial.. But `GoogleSignInResult#isSuccess()` always return `false`. The value of `result.getStatus().getStatusCode();` is `0` which was success accoding to [GoogleAPI's CommonStatusCode](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes)

I researched a bit and found [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android) issues. I have tried

1. Generating a `google-services.json` from SHA key from my application and pasting it in my app folder.
2. Also by generating signed apk and seprately(not running from android studio) installing it in my phone

But none of them works for me.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your tutorial is quite old. Now, Google changed to use Firebase. You can use try this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: @RoShanShan No Luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168573/projects-created-at-console-firebase-google-com-must-use-the-new-firebase-authen

Comment: Follow below tutorial to implement google sign-in in your android app. It is recent article and has all steps to do that. http://www.zoftino.com/google-sign-in-option-in-android-apps

Comment: You can have a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56340297/2289835)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this same exact problem. This occurs when you do not provide the SHA-1 app code when you download the google-services.json.

1. Go to console.firebase.com and create another android app in your project.
2. Fill in ALL the fields including the SHA-1 code.
3. Download the google-services.json
4. Put the google-services.json in the App directory root.