# Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKx available from firebase.google.com/dosc/auth

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, firebase-console, google-signin

I am trying to enable GoogleSignIn for my android app and trying to run [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android) code. I have created the json file from firebase console and pasted it in app. Enabled the google login from firebase but after running app on my phone it gives me error.

```
firebaseError: Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKx available from firebase.google.com/dosc/auth
```

[Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010536/how-to-solve-the-error-projects-created-at-console-firebase-google-com-must-use) threads said to remove firebase client dependency but if I remove it I have compilation error. I also have tried to add latest dependency from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) but no luck.

my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.0.3+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

What am I missing? What dependency I have to add other than firebase -client because if I add the latest the code still doesnt work.

Edit: After removing

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.0.3+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

And adding

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
```

So my dependency looks like this

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

But for Above dependency now I have compilation issues in my code like.

```
For import com.firebase.client.Firebase; Cannot find the symbol client
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus; Cannot find the symbol plus
```

Comment: Do You Enable Google Sign-In in the Firebase console ?

Comment: Do you follow Step 1 in this link. I saw that your gradle missing some lines  https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @RoShanShan yes I have enabled it

Comment: You need to follow 5 steps in this link. Maybe you miss some  configuration. You gradle misses some files from Step 1 https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: That error message indicates that you're using Firebase SDK 2.x, while you have a project that requires Firebase SDK 3 or higher. You shouldn't just *remove* the old SDK, but also *include the new SDK* as in the documentation that RoShan linked. You're at the very least missing `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please check my edits. After removing the dependency and adding new one I am having compilation errors.

Comment: Helpful instructions in the [Firebase Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

Comment: Do you have this `// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in the bottom of gradle?

Comment: You'll also need to upgrade your code to fit the new SDK. See the upgrade guide here: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Answer (score 0):

I have just created new project from  [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin). It 's really easy to follow and sign in. Firebase did all work. You can discover the link below to know which configuration you missed.

[Link to test sing in Google project](https://github.com/ConCaRo/FirebaseTest)

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I tried your code but still the login is failing for me. I am testing it after deploying it to my phone. Is there any other reason for that?