# Google Sign In error 12500

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google Sign In into my app. I don't have a back-end server, I am just getting the details of the logged on Google Account to my app.

I first tried it by using [Google Sign In Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin/app) but I got an error (No code changes made except for printing the stacktrace below). I just used the example SignInActivity as I don't have a back-end server.

```
 Exception com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: 
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzz(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source)
 at com.ewise.android.api.MainActivity.onActivityResult(SignInActivity.java:89)     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7010)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4187)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4234)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1584)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Code

```
 public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
         View.OnClickListener {

     private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
     private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

     private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
     private TextView mStatusTextView;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // Views
         mStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.status);

         // Button listeners
         findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
         findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
         findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

         // [START configure_signin]
         // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
         // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
         GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                 .requestEmail()
                 .build();
         // [END configure_signin]

         // [START build_client]
         // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
         mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
         // [END build_client]

         // [START customize_button]
         // Set the dimensions of the sign-in button.
         SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
         signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
         signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_LIGHT);
         // [END customize_button]
     }

     @Override
     public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();

         // [START on_start_sign_in]
         // Check for existing Google Sign In account, if the user is already signed in
         // the GoogleSignInAccount will be non-null.
         GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
         updateUI(account);
         // [END on_start_sign_in]
     }

     // [START onActivityResult]
     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
         if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
             // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
             // a listener.
             Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
             handleSignInResult(task);
         }
     }
     // [END onActivityResult]

     // [START handleSignInResult]
     private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
         try {
             GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

             // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
             updateUI(account);
         } catch (ApiException e) {
             // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
             // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
             Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
             e.printStackTrace();
             updateUI(null);
         }
     }
     // [END handleSignInResult]

     // [START signIn]
     private void signIn() {
         Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
         startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
     }
     // [END signIn]

     // [START signOut]
     private void signOut() {
         mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
                 .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                         // [START_EXCLUDE]
                         updateUI(null);
                         // [END_EXCLUDE]
                     }
                 });
     }
     // [END signOut]

     // [START revokeAccess]
     private void revokeAccess() {
         mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()
                 .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                         // [START_EXCLUDE]
                         updateUI(null);
                         // [END_EXCLUDE]
                     }
                 });
     }
     // [END revokeAccess]

     private void updateUI(@Nullable GoogleSignInAccount account) {
         if (account != null) {
             mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, account.getDisplayName()));

             findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
             findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         } else {
             mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);

             findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.sign_in_button:
                 signIn();
                 break;
             case R.id.sign_out_button:
                 signOut();
                 break;
             case R.id.disconnect_button:
                 revokeAccess();
                 break;
         }
     }
  }
```

From what I read, the issue could be caused by [SHA1 Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068065/error-12500-in-google-sign-in-8-3-0-when-requesting-requestserverauthcode).

I followed the complete [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) but apparently it's not working.

I copied the SHA1 from gradle **signingReport**

```
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: /Users/user/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: A3:16:3F:43:75:FE:07:62:6D:8D:CC:DD:21:9F:FA:1A
SHA1: 7B:21:26:7F:D8:18:BB:0E:36:1C:82:DD:B7:28:5F:C1:2F:5C:E4:EA
Valid until: Saturday, August 31, 2047
----------
Variant: release
Config: none
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: /Users/user/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: A3:16:3F:43:75:FE:07:62:6D:8D:CC:DD:21:9F:FA:1A
SHA1: 7B:21:26:7F:D8:18:BB:0E:36:1C:82:DD:B7:28:5F:C1:2F:5C:E4:EA
Valid until: Saturday, August 31, 2047
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: /Users/user/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: A3:16:3F:43:75:FE:07:62:6D:8D:CC:DD:21:9F:FA:1A
SHA1: 7B:21:26:7F:D8:18:BB:0E:36:1C:82:DD:B7:28:5F:C1:2F:5C:E4:EA
Valid until: Saturday, August 31, 2047
```

what could be the possible cause of this?

Thanks

P.S. Could this be a possible cause?

```
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11720000 but found 10932470
```

Comment: Hey can you please post your code

Comment: Hi @Dilip I literally used this :) https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin/app. Updated it anyway

Comment: So what happen you get same error or anything else happen.one thing please make one more time SHA1 manually and put at developer console against your APP and cross check package name  and download google-services.json file  and put at app level.

Comment: Yes @Dilip I get the same error. I crossed checked package name. I  even tried using another keystore but the result is the same.

Comment: You need to make code changes to get **your** API key. And yes, you should update the play services

Comment: What a wonderful question. Thanks for asked. Btw how can i get token?

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, all of the answers talking about SHA-1 keys are usually leading you to an "Upload Key" instead of the app signing key. This is auto created in the play console and this solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587610/google-sign-in-throws-an-exception-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexceptio

Answer (score 239, accepted):

**Error PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)**

> This 12500 Error can be solved by adding a **support email address**
>   to your project in *project settings.*    Open link
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/
>
> Select Your project and open settings tab.
>
> Provide a valid support email and restart your application now.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! This error is pretty cryptic, it can mean any of the stuff that are mentioned in the answers here. My problem was this one :(

Comment: I did everything mentioned in the developer console https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in and after spending a day on trying to put SHA-1 fingerprint and all this was the problem. You helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try adding SHA1 key for your project @RohitSingh

Comment: cannot find this public settings option?

Comment: @FazalJarral There is a settings icon at the top left next to title Project Overview click on that and select Project settings in the general tab you can find this Public settings option.

Comment: @MadduSwaroop I have the same issue, but updating email doesn't help at all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587610/google-sign-in-throws-an-exception-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexceptio

Comment: @ViktorApoyan try updating SHA-1 fingerprint of app

Comment: @MadduSwaroop I did also that I even completely removed the firebase project and created a new one,  I am not able to use the Sign In button not from debug build not from release.

Comment: I'm now getting a different error but that's an improvement. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Just adding it here that, I was facing this issue in emulator and things were working on real device

Comment: release.keystore & debug.keystore are separate files so make sure that you have the SHA1 key for both.

Answer (score 56):

Check if SHA-1 fingerprints are added to the firebase project settings. If not,find SHA-1 fingerprint using

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Also, find the SHA-1 fingerprint of release key using

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore path>
```

Remove `<keystore path>` with the path of the key store.

Then add both SHA-1 fingerprints to firebase projects settings.

NB: Don't forget to replace google-services.json with updated google-services.json with new fingerprints. I lost two days on that.

#### While debug

Android studio automatically [generate](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode) `~/.android/debug.keystore` on first **debug build** and use it to sign the app.

To get the SHA-1 run (password `android`) ([doc](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)):

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

This `SHA-1` should be added to the app settings at `firebase` to allow usage of google sign in capabilities while testing debug build.

Comment: How are you certain he's using Firebase?

Comment: Guessed it (similarity in code and serverless). Firebase project is also connected to the GCP console. We can also change fingerprints in GCP credentials.

Comment: same error with, but in my case it was not related to firebase (i'm not using it).

Comment: Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials   .Add new credential (O Auth Client) with SHA key. (Firebase automatically does this for our firebase projects)

Comment: The google-services.json file can be found in the app directory inside your project. (Go through Finder / File Explorer)

Comment: @NiyasNazar earlier it was working fine, When I changed my laptop it is showing me same error,
Then I generated sha-1 from my current laptop and added this in firebase console.. still having same error. signInResult:failed code=12500. if you can help me

Comment: @Tarun what about google-services.json. Do you update it with new SHA-1?

Comment: Found the solution , it contained two client_id and I used different 1. Thank you for your answer @NiyasNazar

Comment: It promped me to the debug keystore's password, I left it blank and it worked.

Comment: adding SHA-1 solved for me (I have added de sha-256 only)

Answer (score 55):

Support email and also **all project and privacy links** are necessary for Google SignIn to work, otherwise it throws 12500.

Set it on  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials on the bottom of second tab named "OAuth consent screen" - there you'll find three links that need to be configured.

This is not mentioned ANYWHERE in the Firebase guides.

Comment: Thanks, it is working for me. I have wasted almost whole days to resolving the problem

Comment: Thanks, I just added one of the 'authorised domains' to the privacy links and everything worked. You saved me some hours of trial and error 

Comment: This should be accepted answer. I have been struggling with that 2 days, without any success. Google should update guides, for now their documentation is misleading, their guide will never work and error code tells nothing

Comment: where to add privacy links?

Comment: On second tab named "OAuth consent screen" - on the bottom of the form you've got three links

Comment: To set Email and Privacy Policy : Click on "OAuth consent screen" -> Click on "Edit App". Now you can see both options.

Comment: Is there an option to generate the policy and privacy links from firebase?

Comment: @Coco I have the same issue, but the problem that I don't have any personal domain? how I can solve this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587610/google-sign-in-throws-an-exception-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexceptio

Comment: @ViktorApoyan I guess buy one?

Answer (score 53):

[image]for error 12500 You need to add support gmail in settings of firebase only and for error 10 add ssh fingerprint in firebase console as you see in picture

Comment: good and straight forward answer, Just configured my gmail account and bam it does the rest

Comment: "for error 12500 You need to add support gmail in settings of firebase only and for error 10 add ssh fingerprint in firebase console as you see in picture" This really helped. I was getting 12500, applied SHA1 fingerprint and it still wasn't working. Adding the SUPPORT EMAIL helped. Thanks!

Comment: @Vijay I have a same issue but adding email address does not solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587610/google-sign-in-throws-an-exception-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexceptio Please help

Answer (score 49):

Simply update your Google Play Services to the latest version (or 11720000 in this case). If you are using AVD, Nexus 5 and 5X images support Google Play. Once the emulator is up and running, go to the Extended Controls Menu >  Google Play then update.

Comment: How to do it on Samsung devices?

Comment: This is not the issue in my case. The Google Play services are already up to date.

Comment: @zub0r's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57007750/2253682) regarding **project and privacy links** should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Please where is the extended controls menu, on the emulator or on visual studio?

Answer (score 21):

Try updating the OAuth consent screen on
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: I had to add support email and then it started working. This was in flutter.

Comment: Also all project and privacy links are necessary, otherwise it throws 12500. This is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @zub0r links are not necessary. Source: I just did it without them.

Answer (score 20):

I was stuck of this for a while.

Make sure these step are performed-

- Correct SHA key is saved on Firebase Console.
- Download the latest google-service.json
- And Last and **most important**   Save OAuth consent under credentials in google api, 
  [OAuth Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdT0z.jpg) This took a long to figure out.
  And it worked fine after this.

Comment: well. this should be the accepted answer for 2019 here. the google strangely "must" update the content inside *OAuth Consent*

Comment: Ugh, another vote for this. Totally was my obscure problem.

Answer (score 19):

Seems your SHA1 is overwritten by Google play store.
Check in your google play store, launch panel, under app signing, see if google play has an additional SHA1 added.

And copy that SHA1, add to your relevant place, would do the job.

Comment: oh my god! Thank you for this tip! App Bundles created its own SHA1, so the release keys that are used locally (when generating APKs) isn't the correct one anymore.

Comment: This is the most confusing workflow ever. But thanks for the tip

Comment: Wow. I was looking for this for days. Thank you so much. Worked well. (Ionic/Android).

Comment: Awesome man, I've added the release sha1, but I needed to add this one too

Comment: This worked for me. I added SHA-1 of my app on Google Play Store in firebase.

Answer (score 12):

Enable Google Sign in method works for me
-Authentication->Sign-in method->google
[image]

Answer (score 12):

1. Enable Sign-in method GOOGLE.**  (not necessary)

[image]

2. **Open the project settings.**

[image]

3. Provide email for support.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In my case, the issue was that my emulator did not have Play Store. I have made the emulator (named API 23) through Visual Studio, because I develop using Xamarin.Forms as well, and in Visual Studio's Android Device Manager you can select if your emulator should have Google Play Store.

Had to create an emulator through Android Studio's AVD and ensure that it had Play Store:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I tried every other possible suggestion in this massive thread.

Answer (score 6):

If there's still anyone out there with a similar issue, if you're adding custom scopes, make sure it's a valid scope. In my case, I mixed Facebook scopes with Google scopes and took me a while to figure it out!

Comment: i used [email, name]. The correct version was [email, profile]

Answer (score 6):

I think the error came from the Wrong SHA1. Please don't forget that the SHA1 is different between release and debug mode in the android studio. Instead of using keytool to get the SHA1, you can use Gradle project -> Task -> android -> signingReport in the android studio (can open it by menu View -> Toolwindow -> gradle ) to get release and debug SHA1. After that, for easy working, you need to create 2 separate credentials with two SHA1 on google cloud console (google just instruct to create 1 using release SHA1, when we develop it will not work since it uses the debug SHA1).

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Firebase Authentication. My SHA-1 was indicated correctly, client id was also correct but I still was getting 12500.

It turned out that my problem was that I didn't indicate **Support email** in my project settings. (Settings -> General tab -> Your project (Public settings) section).

Comment: Same thing happened for me as well. There is serious documentation issues with google's services. I wish they documented such issues or at least show a user friendly error.

Comment: When a domain is used on the consent screen or in an OAuth client’s configuration, it must be pre-registered here. If your app needs to go through verification, please go to the Google Search Console to check if your domains are authorized. Learn more about the authorized domain limit.

anyone knows what to enter here?

Comment: @ashish-goel this is now documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/troubleshooting-faq#android-app-error12500

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this error was there because android auth was removed by senior team as it seems there's no need of android key in backend authentication. So both Android and Web client keys are needed in google login.

Comment: Thanks for this! I also deleted my Android client ID because I thought it's not needed since we only need the web client ID.

Answer (score 5):

Go to your project in the Firebase console, open Project Settings, add your SHA certificate fingerprints there. Download the updated google-services.json file and add it to your Projects app folder.

This worked for me.

[image: Firebase console Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

First make sure you registered your app in the [google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com)

Make sure you have both the `debug` and `release` keys in your Firebase application. If it this error appears in production, add your `SHA-1 release key` to fire base app. If it appears in development, then add your `SHA-1 debug key`.

[image: Where to add SHA-1 finger print]

Getting the debug/release key:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias [your alias] -keystore [path/to/debug or release.keystore]
```

Make sure to download the updated `google-services.json` to your app.

Comment: I was failing with GoogleSignInResult.getSuccess() returning false and a code of 12500.  Ultimately, it was that someone else had setup my OAuth with their SHA1 instead of my debug key.  This fixed it.

Comment: @Reckless I'm glad this helped!

Answer (score 4):

**If you are coming** here from **flutter** : This is one of the corner cases we have to fix as per the documentation here : https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in
[image]

- Go to [Google APIs & Sevices](http://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/)
- Select the app you want to implement google signin In to.
- **Then click on Enable APIS and Services**

[image]

- **Then Search for Google Peoples API**

[image]

- Open the Google People API card and click enable, your app might get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of the answers and still was getting `12500`. It turned out that the solution for me was even simpler - my project has `User Type` set to `internal` and I was trying to log in with email outside of my company. So if none of the previous answers work for you, check if you have `User Type` set to internal or external and if you try to log in with acceptable account.

[image]

Comment: The answer is old but still works. Thanks, you make my life easier!

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was using a 'release' ClientID with my debug-configured app. Make sure you have a release and a debug keys, using each SHA-1's respectively.

Answer (score 2):

When your app authenticates with a backend server or accesses Google APIs from your backend server, then you must pass the OAuth 2.0 client ID that was created for your server to the requestIdToken method when you construct the GoogleSignInOptions object, for accessing the user's basic profile information. Also, don't forget to submit the support email in the OAuth consent screen found in the Credentials page in the API Console.

Answer (score 2):

After I tried all solutions above and nothing has worked.
I found that I am requesting scope that is not mentioned in the cloud.
These is my code

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/openid',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'
    ]);
```

After I removed all scopes, it worked.

My scopes section was empty:
[image]

Scopes tab can be found here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit

Answer (score 1):

**It can also happen that the cordova compiler is unable to find the proper keystore file.**

**Solution:** Before executing `ionic cordova build android` specify the **signing properties**

**Step-1**: Generate a debug keystore file

Execute the command

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Use password: `android`

**Step-2:** Copy the keystore file(`debug.keystore`) from `~/.android` to `platform/android` directory of your current project

**Step-3:** Create a file named **release-signing.properties** in the `platform/android` directory

**Step-4:** Add the contents in the file

```
storeFile=debug.keystore
keyAlias=androiddebugkey
storePassword=android
keyPassword=android
```

> Note: These are the default values. If you have provided custom alias and password then use them accordingly.

**Step-5:** Now build `ionic cordova build android`

Comment: Hello,
where is platform/android directory what is it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem after opening my project on another computer (different Android Studio).
In my case, I solved it using the Firebase Assistant, which I had used to setup Firebase initially. 
Opened the Firebase Assistant (Tools > Firebase) and selecting Authentication > Connect.
This reconnected the project to Firebase and updated the configs

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the Google Login issue since 2 week, finally sorted it well .let me explain the reason.
The issue was related with firebase. In firebase , they mentioned a field "support email " as optional . But once i added it (any of your personal email)  ,the issue sorted and i got the response .
If your getting an error as 12501 , then it is related to settings in your google account.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck of this for a while.

Make sure these step are performed-

```
Correct SHA key is saved on Firebase Console.
Valid reversed client id.
from fcm console=>select app=>from authentication=>enable google sign-in method
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it seems silly but I had this error in my emulator and the issue was resolved when I booted up an emulator that had Google Play API's installed.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue,updating the support email and the OAuth consent screen form didn't work, however adding the Google Play Store App signing key certificate to the Firebase Console Worked:

1. Copy the App Signing Key from the Google Play Console(Setup -> App Integrity -> App Signing)

[image]

Notice that these keys were randomly generated and are not my project's keys.

2. Add the Keys to Firebase console.

[image]

Comment: I would NEVER put up fingerprint like this in public be careful even when it's dev project.

Comment: @helloworld331 the screenshot above contains random fingerprints that I generated [here](https://onlinehashtools.com/generate-random-md5-hash)

Comment: I don't think it is a random key from app integrity in console.

Comment: I generated and edited it using devtools, the content you see is modified HTML

Comment: I see. Good idea!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled with this error for many hours and tried everything suggested from everyone (I even created another firebase project with a clean app containing only a login button to isolate everything as much as possible) but I found that my error was that the login I was trying to perform was with my company-related google account, which turns out that is not suitable for my personal Firebase google login configuration.

Definitely Firebase should add more info for this 12500 error code, it is just too generic...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because of the wrong Google Client Id.
I change my key to the key listed in `google-services.json` (under `oauth_client` object)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have following things set up properly:

1. Generate Client Id in your Google Project.
2. Provide proper SHA-1 key for that Client Id. (debug / release)
3. Provide proper package name for that Client Id.
4. Make sure you have generated Client Id in `strings.xml`, `google-services.json` or `credentials.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in 
follow this api documentation but keep in mind that inside WEB_CLIENT_ID use the value of client id which is generated inside google-services.json file.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private val TAG = "JSAGoogleSignIn"
private val REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 1234
private val WEB_CLIENT_ID = "354298333018-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

private var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var txt_register = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_register)
    txt_register.setOnClickListener {
        var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, RegisterActivity::class.java)
        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(WEB_CLIENT_ID)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
    mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build()

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    sign_in_button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
    }

}


override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}


private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
    if (user != null) {
        Log.e("Email", "Value" + user.email)
    }

}

fun signIn() {

}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val currentUser = mAuth!!.currentUser
    updateUI(currentUser)
}

public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {
        val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
        if (result.isSuccess) {
            // successful -> authenticate with Firebase
            val account = result.signInAccount
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account!!)
        } else {
            // failed -> update UI
            updateUI(null)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "SignIn: failed!" + result.status,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    Log.e(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle():" + acct.id!!)

    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.idToken, null)
    mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success
                    Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential: Success!")
                    val user = mAuth!!.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    // Sign in fails
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential: Failed!", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Authentication failed!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, After adding fingerprint in Firebase console, it got automatically picked up by the Google developer console and shown the fingerprints. But sign in did not work. After looking at every step, I figured that Google reversed my manifest file package like this `com.xxxxxxxx.app`. But it is actually `app.xxxxxxxx.com`, in Google developer console. So I deleted auto created a fingerprint and added fingerprint with the correct package name. BOOM!!. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error appeared to me when the Google option was not enabled, 
[as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGRSy.png).

It happened when I changed Google's account and forgot to turn on the option of connecting with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project should not contain any special character including numeric or any kind of symbol(project name should be simple as  com.google.testproject)

Comment: That's call Project package name not project name

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working on a non-production app, the issue was that when creating a project in firebase console, there were issues synchronizing SHA-1 keys back and forth from Firebase & Google developer consoles. So, I decided to create the project first on the Google Developer console, and then select it when creating a new project on Firebase console.

I also made a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/_tpnqOeXvvk) for this, that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone should start debugging by running this before building a release or a debug versions of apps.

```
flutter clean
```

everytime you change `google-services.json` or `AndroidManifest.xml` files

Nothing worked before I ran this command

Flutter official doc also mention this

```
 Note: You may need to run flutter clean after changing the gradle file. This prevents cached builds from affecting the signing process.
```

[image]

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle

EDIT: I made it work in both production or development envs. After few days of testing, I encounter this issue again and I was testing different versions of apps installing and uninstalling and upgrading all that stuff. I could not fix it with anything but running `flutter clean` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your SHA-1 ready within in your Firebase project settings, you can test your application using a **Physical** device instead of using an **Emulator**.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably know is that you need to add the debug and release sign in keys of your flutter android app to the Firebase project.

You find the debug key by doing this from your project folder:

```bash
stephanedeluca@Angelantonio2019:~/development/OlenPEPS-mobile$ cd android
stephanedeluca@Angelantonio2019:~/development/OlenPEPS-mobile/android$ ./gradlew signingReport
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: /Users/stephanedeluca/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: 4B:7A:AA:...:61:C7
SHA1: 17:B3:67:...:59:EA
SHA-256: DE:2A:E0:...:F1:45
Valid until: jeudi 6 août 2043
----------
Variant: release
Config: release
Store: /Users/stephanedeluca/upload-keystore.jks
Alias: upload
MD5: FC:CD:...:FD:3C
SHA1: D5:F3:...:6A:26
SHA-256: 77:7A:...:67:3F
Valid until: dimanche 26 septembre 2049
----------
```

As you can see, the debug SHA key sits at the very beginning of the log. Copy it.

Now, go to your Firebase project on the Web and open project settings like so:

[image: Firebase project settings]

Scroll down to the keys and tap add and paste the debug key.

[image]

Now for the release version: *do not take the one listed at release section: Play store use its own key.

So get to the Play store console and head to the App integrity section as follows; copy the SHA1:

[image: Play store app integrity]

Now add it to Firebase the same way you did with the debug key.

And voilà!

Answer (score -1):

My solution: (edit: 04/Jan/2019)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try this options:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test
```

It prompts for password and just enter password. You can see the SHA1, MD5 fingerprints.

[image]