# google signin failed in playstore apk android

Tags: android, firebase, apk, release, google-signin

[image]Google signin working in debug apk. Sometimes run in release apk ,sometimes not. When I tried on playstore app, it is never successful.

I used firebase as backend. I am confused what was the right solution.

I tried to generate new "Client ID" & "Client Secret" for firebase.                    NOTE : I added "SHA1 key of Upload certificate" from google play console.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: @Arahasya 12500 status code when checking in debuggable release apk

Comment: @Arahasya is this problem regarding release key  sha1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500

Comment: @Arahasya already watched that link.. how I can update my google play services ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below steps
 - Go to your app playstore dashboard
 - Click on release management
 - click on app signing Copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint
 - Go to your firebase console
 - Go to project settings
 - Add the sha finger print there

Comment: hey bro ramees , first thank you for reposnse.. On my google play console there is 2 things are showing  -       1.App signing certificate    2. Upload certificate

Comment: so, what should I do now .. i dont know where these 2 things come from.. also there is some note also i.e "Google Play App Signing is enabled for this app"

Comment: edited the answer with more details... I faced similar issue...and this solution worked for me....Good luck

Comment: should I again download new google services json file and generate new signed apk

Comment: no... In my case..it started working without again downliading google services json..

Comment: bro thans a lot .. can i join you on any social media? you saved my day

Comment: Ya... it will be great if you can subscribe to my channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCELTpUnU4lBjGxvFh2yXj6w?view_as=subscriber and my facebook page - https://www.facebook.com/codesfor

Comment: This worked for me to. Thank you Ramees!
PS: for the new Google Play Console interface, you have to go in:
Left menu > Setup > App signing > Copy the SHA-1 > paste it in SHA certificate fingerprints. Also for me worked without re-upload another aab/apk.

Comment: You don't need to redownload the google_services.json file, It should work immediately as soon as you add the sha1 fingerprint