# How to solve this GMS ApiExcpetion: Error Code 12500?

Tags: java, android

This is the exception I'm getting: **com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    /* if (CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode() == requestCode) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);*/
    if (requestCode == googleRequestCode) {
        //for google
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
```

Comment: Consider formatting your code next time before you post it here. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I recently resolved this issue in one of my projects and the possible reasons are below:

- In case of google authentication, you must include your **SHA1** values for your debug and release keystores on both consoles like [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) as well as [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com).
- After completing above step download a latest google.json file fron firebase console and add that file into your project.

Your **12500** error will be resolved.

Credit goes to: [Exception com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094767/exception-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-12500)