# Firebase UI login with Google is failing due to 12500(SIGN_IN_FAILED) error code

Tags: firebaseui

I am using Firebase UI to provide login for my app. When i try to login with Google it is giving error message `com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 12500, message: 12500`. But i when try to integrate google login directly it is working fine. I Couldn't find the way to resolve this issue. Error code description in google document

> The sign in attempt didn't succeed with the current account.

Unlike SIGN_IN_REQUIRED. when seeing this error code, there is nothing user can do to recover from the sign in failure. Switching to another account may or may not help. Check adb log to see details if any.

Answer (score 12):

Check to see if you have added a "Support email" in your firebase project settings. This was able to solve the problem for me after a lot of trying different things that didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You may need to set a SHA-1 certificate fingerprint in your app's Firebase settings. See this answer to a similar question here (reproduced below): 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52082447/4982525

> Check if SHA-1 fingerprints are added to the firebase project
>   settings. If not,find SHA-1 fingerprint using
>
> https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth
>
> Also, find the SHA-1 fingerprint of release key using
>
> `keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore path>`
>
> Remove  with the path of the key store.
>
> Then add both SHA-1 fingerprints to firebase projects settings.
>
> NB: Don't forget to replace google-services.json with updated
>   google-services.json with new fingerprints. I lost two days on that.

Answer (score 1):

Please add sha-1 code from your android studio to the fire console.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found that just deleting the `app("remove app")` from the firebase project solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently, the fix was to goto: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and complete OAuth credentials.
Add app logo, email, authorized domain, privacy link, and terms link. In my case, I used example.com for most stuffs, just for a practice app.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Firebase project on your google console. And select the appropriate providers in Authentication.

The issue was you didn't set up authentication on your console project.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent many hours dealing with this error, I tried everything posted here (review SHA-1 fingerprints, support email, fill all configuration in Google cloud console, etc.), I just realised I was doing the login tests with my job-related email (which is not exactly a regular google account). I just wanted to leave my experience here just in case someone can spend less hours than I did with this issue...