# Android Google sigin getting an ApiException "12500"

Tags: android, google-signin

In my android app, I have to implement Google SigIn Option but Debug Apk its working fine and I'm getting Expected result. In SignedApk(published app) getting a **siginError:'12500'**

I tried with this [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    signInButton = findViewById(R.id.signInButtonGoogle);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    setGooglePlusButtonText(signInButton, "Continue with Google");
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (new AppPermissions(LoginActivity.this).checkPermission()) {
                signIn();
            }
        }
    });



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            updateUI(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            updateUI(null);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate the SHA fingerprint of your release key and  add SHAH key to google project

Comment: Is this because I'm using two google accounts??
1.for Firebase
2.for Google Maps and Google sign in

Comment: Signed Apk also running fine while installing manually.
but after installing from play store I'm getting the same error