# error: "code: 12500, message: 12500:" after release but not in debug

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I run the app in android studios it works fine, but after release I receive the message:

> code: 12500, message: 12500:

When I try to sign in via Google (sign in via Email is works)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
After reserching what sha1 was i realized that there is a different SHA1 key for relese mode. It is found in "manage versions" > "app signing"

Answer (score 0):

Check if SHA-1 fingerprints are added to the firebase project settings