# Google Sign-In ApiException: 10: on a published App

Tags: java, android, firebase, exception, google-signin

I've been getting the ApiException 10 error when trying ot sign up with google. BEFORE YOU MARK THIS AS DUPLICATE: My question differs from others 'cause **my App IS published on the playstore.**

I've been getting ApiException 12500 while using debug and release SHA-1's until I figured I had to use Google Play's sha-1 'cause it's published.

Ok, set, but now I have an `ApiException: 10:`. The Client IDs I tried are the one I created in the Google Devs console (as Web App since I use **Firebase**) and the one written inside the `google-services.json.`

Is it messing up 'cause I'm using google play's SHA-1 or did I miss something? Would it work if I'd be to release it on the store? HOW do I program a Google Sign In and test it before publishing if my App is already on the store?

Btw before someone comes up with it, support mail is there and google auth is enabled.

Comment: I've said that using 3 keys doesn't work. Which is the suggested answer there

Comment: Please cross check the applicationId in defaultConfig inside build.gradle with your application on firebase account.I'm sure there might be some error.

Comment: still nothing....

Answer (score 0):

Okay first things first, Have you added your SHA-1 for both debug and release to your Firebase Project? If yes, have you updated your google-services.json in your Android project ?

Also try updating your Google Play services once.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313867/8450534) answer once if it helps. It's an really unpredictable solution, still give it a shot if it works

Comment: Play-Services is up to date and if I try running it with all 3 keys I get back to an ApiException 12500.
So.. I'm only using the PlayStore Sha-1 to test it now

Comment: Did you check the link to another answer that i have provided?

Comment: I have said in the last line that I have a support mail added