# error (ApiException: 12500) was detected and the support email, sha-1 key was checked but not resolved

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

There are apps that use Firebase Google authentication. When I get the request for this app, I copy the project and change the package name, connect the app to the FireBase with that person's Google account, and provide the app. However, I recently created the app in exactly the same way, but I get an error (ApiException: 12500).

I also changed the SHA-1 key value and confirmed support email, but the same problem is repeated.

Did this error occur because duplicate SHA-1 key values were used? However, changing the SHA-1 key value does not solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

Comment: See my answer here, i'm sure this is the same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012033/firebase-sign-in-googlesignin-onactivityresult-returns-result-canceled-with-r/57022055