# Firebase Google Auth not working . ApiException: 12500: , null

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

yes 
everything is well set up in the firebase and flutter 
1) added the latest SHA-1 fingerprint in the firebase project
2) enabled the google sign in option
3) added the supported email

the app is still in debug 
added the debug key SHA-1

nothing is working

I'm  just trying to set up a simple Google Auth sign in which i couldn't

i'm getting this error

PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)

`

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth;


  Future<FirebaseUser> SignInWithGoogleAuth() async {

    GoogleSignInAccount GSA = await googleSignIn.signIn();
//I'm getting error here  ^^ at the above line code
     googleAuth = await GSA.authentication;
     AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
     FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    print('signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user');
    return currentUser;

  }
```

**Error:**

```
SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = borse.coaching_app
V/Monotype(22482):     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default

E/flutter (22482): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled 

Exception: **PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)**


E/flutter (22482): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
E/flutter (22482): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:302:33)
E/flutter (22482): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22482): #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:226:58)
E/flutter (22482): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22482): #3      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:268:20)
E/flutter (22482): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:339:48)
E/flutter (22482): #5      _StartingPageState.SignInWithGoogleAuth (package:coaching_app/pages/startingPage.dart:27:50)
E/flutter (22482): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22482): #6      _StartingPageState.GoogleImg.<anonymous closure> (package:coaching_app/pages/startingPage.dart:141:26)
E/flutter (22482): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22482): #7      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
E/flutter (22482): #8      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
E/flutter (22482): #9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
E/flutter (22482): #10     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
E/flutter (22482): #11     TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:177:9)
E/flutter (22482): #12     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:436:9)
E/flutter (22482): #13     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
E/flutter (22482): #14     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
E/flutter (22482): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:221:19)
E/flutter (22482): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22)
E/flutter (22482): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (22482): #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (22482): #19     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (22482): #20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (22482): #21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (22482): #22     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (22482): #23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
E/flutter (22482): #24     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
E/flutter (22482):
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

Comment: looked at this too before,
did all the stuff and solution in that,
still the same error

Comment: @HarshBorse see my answer, I'm pretty sure that's the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012033/firebase-sign-in-googlesignin-onactivityresult-returns-result-canceled-with-r/57022055#57022055. Feel free to upvote if it's working for you =)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error **ApiException: 12500** for a long time. I have tried everything:

- remove my debugkeystore, recreate one
- add a support email on the firebase console
- change plugin versions
- update google on my device

Nothing worked but looking for a solution I found:

I went to this page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)
Select your project from the list (top left). Then go to "Oauth consent screen"

I filled out the app's logo and link on the app's homepage and application's privacy policy link (with the project.firebaseapp.com), and then saved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd5ur.jpg)

After that it was good. I believe the official documentation should be updated.

For more information visit this link
[enter link description here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33393#)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also "enter link description here" is not a good format of your question.