# Google Sign in error code 12500 , message 12500

Tags: java, android

> I add google sign in my android app but it gives me an error`" code: 
>   12500 message:12500"`. I use an external emulator (Samsung Galaxy J7 
>   pro ) for testing. kindly help me, please if I log in with email then works 
>   fine kindly ignore the imports  .i tried all kind of solution like checking 
>   sha-1 fingerprint client id but it does not work

*

Here is my Code

```
    import com.example.muhammadtehmoor.guardian_module.Model.User;
    import com.example.muhammadtehmoor.guardian_module.utils.Common;
    import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
    import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
    import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
    import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
    import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
    import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
    import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
    import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
    import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import io.paperdb.Paper;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        DatabaseReference user_information;
        private static final  int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 2552;
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Paper.init(this);

            user_information = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.USER_INFORMATION);

            providers = Arrays.asList(

                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
            );

            Dexter.withActivity(this)
                    .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {

                            showSignInOptions();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you must accept permission to use app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

                        }
                    }).check();

        }

        private void showSignInOptions() {

          startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                  .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                  .setAvailableProviders(providers)
          .build(),MY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {

                IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    user_information.orderByKey()
                            .equalTo(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if(dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) // if user is not exit
                                    {
                                        if(!dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) // if key user id is not exist
                                        {
                                            Common.loggedUser = new User(firebaseUser.getUid() , firebaseUser.getEmail());

                                            // add to the database

                                            user_information.child(Common.loggedUser.getUid())
                                                    .setValue(Common.loggedUser);


                                        }

                                    }

                                    else //if user is available
                                    {
                                        Common.loggedUser = dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).getValue(User.class);

                                    }

                                    //save UID to Storage to update location from background
    //                                Paper.book().write(common.USER_UID_SAVE_KEY,Common.loggedUser.getUid());
                                    Paper.book().write(Common.USER_UID_SAVE_KEY , Common.loggedUser.getUid() );

                                    updateToken(firebaseUser);
                                    setupUI();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                }

            }
        }

        private void setupUI() {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavActivity.class));
            finish();


        }



        private void updateToken(final FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {

            final DatabaseReference tokens =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.TOKENS);

            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                    tokens.child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .setValue(instanceIdResult.getToken());
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my user class which contain getters and setters

```
package com.example.muhammadtehmoor.guardian_module.Model;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class User {

    private String uid,email;
    private HashMap<String , User> acceptedList; // list user friends


    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public HashMap<String, User> getAcceptedList() {
        return acceptedList;
    }

    public void setAcceptedList(HashMap<String, User> acceptedList) {
        this.acceptedList = acceptedList;
    }
```

Here is my common class which contains variables

```
public class Common

   {


    public static final String USER_UID_SAVE_KEY = "SaveUid";
    public static final String TOKENS ="Tokens" ;
    public static final String FROM_NAME ="FromName" ;
    public static final String ACCEPT_LIST = "acceptedList";
    public static final String FROM_UID = "FromUid";
    public static final String TO_UID = "ToUid";
    public static final String TO_NAME = "ToName";
    public static final String FRIEND_REQUEST = "FriendRequests" ;
    public static String USER_INFORMATION = "UserInformation";
    public static User loggedUser;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

Answer (score 0):

Update your Google Play Services to the latest version. 
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47645136/7765316)

and see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47632035/7765316) aswell

Answer (score 0):

Check that the SHA-1 key in the Firebase project connected to the app matches the signing key from Android studio.

Comment: what do u mean by sign in key from android studio

Comment: Not sign in signing. There is gradle on the right pane in Android studio, under app you will see signingReport, run it and it will display a SHA-1 key, copy it and paste it in FIrebase, for your debug version of app to work with Firebase