# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

when i create my first project on firebase to use google signin authentication. my app successfully run and completer google signin.
But when i develop my second project on the firebase i do the same thing like add SHA1 and add support email, but when i tried to google signin from  my app , it shows

```
sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500
```

I don't know why this error come.

Is there any condition that

1) we can't use a same SHA1 key to a different apps.

2) we can't user the same email id for 'support email' inside the google sign for the two projects

or please tell me there is any other condition regarding the using of multiple project on  a same account of firebase.

Comment: check [android - Google Sign In error 12500 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

Answer (score 0):

Input both SHA-1 and SHA256.
Make sure you have added a Support Email.
Update Google Play Services.

If all of these fail, delete your keystore and generate a new one.

These are the issues that cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error **ApiException: 12500** for a long time. I have tried everything:

- remove my debugkeystore, recreate one
- add a support email on the firebase console
- change plugin versions
- update google on my device

Nothing worked but looking for a solution I found:

I went to this page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) Select your project from the list (top left). Then go to "Oauth consent screen"

I filled out the app's logo and link on the app's homepage and application's privacy policy link (with the project.firebaseapp.com), and then saved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6ZRC.jpg)

After that it was good. I believe the official documentation should be updated.

For more information visit this link 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33393#issuecomment-510395178)