# Google sign in issue: "failed message=12500"

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth

I m trying to migrate google sign in from one account to another in my android app. I have add the package name and sha1 key into new account and then also added the"google-services.json" file. But every time i m running it, it shows me "failed message=12500".

I have tried everything, looked at all the solutions everywhere.

When i use the old account and old "google-services.json" file it works but as soon i tried to migrate to new account it doesn't work. The crazy thing about this is that i m using other services as well like firebase notification, phone authentication and remote config they all work perfectly fine in the new account, but not google sign.

Comment: Do none of the solutions from here work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500

Comment: Are sure that there is no manually added keys left in any xml files related to old one ?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

Add application logo, Application Homepage link and Application Privacy Policy link. To add both link you can just copy and paste from Authorized domains section from "oAuth consent screen", for example: your-app-abc123.firebaseapp.com

This is a must step for migrating or adding a new app, because i spent hours and hours and with no results and only this thing helped me out.