# Error Code 12500 when trying to implement google sign in for android

Tags: java, android, google-signin

So I've been getting error 12500 for 3 days now and I've looked at every possible post to try and resolve the error. I've updated google play services, updated the google console to make sure there are supporting links and added a profile image. IM NOT USING FIREBASE. I'm just using google console. The error seems to be happening when I create the GoogleSignInAccount account.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        String idToken = account.getIdToken();
        System.out.println(idToken);
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        updateUI(null);
    }
}
```

W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: 
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source:8)
            at edu.lehigh.cse216.phase0.ui.login.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:90)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
            at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500) and second one please read latest docs of google sign in method.