# Google Sign In: ApiException 12500 (only on Android 10 devices)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, android-10.0

**Summarize the problem**

I want to/already have integrate/integrated the Google-Login as described by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).
It works... at least I thought so.
After publishing the app in the Play store I got feedback that the login via google isn't working on devices that have Android 10 installed --> only on Android 10, weird

In Android Studio I get the following message/error when trying it with Android 10:

```
Exception com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500:
```

**Describe what you have tried**

I have tried multiple things:

- Everything is up-to-date
- `targetSdkVersion` set to Android 10, sane thing for `compileSdkVersion`
- Literally anthing mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500) (Support mail set; Fingerprint is corret, ... as said before, it works on e.g. Android 9 devices)

Info: I am not using firebase.
This is my first post here, hopefully I didn't mess up my question.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500

Comment: @МухаммадМагомедов this is the link I have mentioned above (thrid bullet point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147523/14286853

This worked for me... in the beginning.
I just found out that changing the SHA1 back to the release key that I have locally --> it worked.

I have no idea why it worked in the first place and after some time it stopped.

If you have the same problem:

- Double check SHA1 key set in Google/Firebase
- I found out that OAuth-Screen that could also cause this problem --> be aware of that