# Google Sign In failed Android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-signin

I have integrated google signin into my app. i have also genererated release mode key using

```
 c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore c:\you_key_here.key
```

when signing in using google in i am getting api exception.....

```
W/AuthActivity: Google sign in failed
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: 
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.0.0:9)
    at com.midzone.arabiannew.AuthActivity.onActivityResult(AuthActivity.java:95)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5278)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2220)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8019)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

i have mentioned both libraries

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0'
```

It seems there is some api mismatch. what could be the solution for this. any help?

Comment: Check this [ApiException: 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500) answers.

Comment: i am doing it in latest android 10 samsung device. if you read the stack trace you can check both are different. i think this is not the solution. i had checked this link before posting my question.