# ApiException: 12500: on 1 device but not on another

Tags: android

I am prototyping an app which uses the user's Google Account.
This is how I request it:

```
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions);
```

Additionally I did the following:

- Added the app in Google Clout Platform with debug SHA1. The app will not be release in Play Store, so I don't care for release SHA1.
- Added my support E-Mail and Logo for the consent screen. The app is set as external
- Created Firebase project

The whole thing works for my developer account which I have on the device. I log in and later I am able to consume the account.

However, when I install the very same app on another device, which has different Google Account, I get ApiException 12500:

> 2021-08-03 13:13:28.775 24691-24691/com.ribui.pom24 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.ribui.pom24, PID: 24691
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.ribui.pom24/com.ribui.pom24.app.MainActivity}: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500:
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4324)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
> Caused by: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500:
> at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:3)
> at com.ribui.pom24.app.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:171)
> at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4320)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
> Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500:
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.6.0:3)
> at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.2.0:3)
> at com.ribui.pom24.app.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:161)
> at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4320) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
> 2021-08-03 13:13:32.808 24691-24691/com.ribui.pom24 E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Error handling uncaught exception
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.Utils.awaitEvenIfOnMainThread(Utils.java:122)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:231)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$1.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:154)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:54)
> at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
> at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
> at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1953)
> 2021-08-03 13:13:33.015 24691-24691/com.ribui.pom24 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24691 SIG: 9

I tried to add this second account as test user (though I would like to avoid setting users) but it is a still no go.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

Comment: Unfortunately none of these help. Again, it works for my account, but not for different one ...