# Firebase Google Sign In Not Working In Android 11 (Red Velvet Cake)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a Sign In Activity using Firebase authentication. It work successfully on Android Lollipop and on android Pie. However, if I run it on android 11 (Red Velvet), it doesnt work and I got the following message when i hit the login button:

```
2022-01-13 19:27:13.842 8122-8122/com.example.riset_login_firebase W/GoogleActivity: Google sign in failed

com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: 
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:4)
  at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.2.0:3)
  at com.example.riset_login_firebase.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:72)
```

And here is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.riset_login_firebase;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SignInButton button;
    private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        button = findViewById(R.id.login);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sign();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sign() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        if(user != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500 or some of the many other pages that show up when [searching for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+sign+in+failed+com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException%3A+12500?

Comment: Have you tried to implement [Google Identity One Tap](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d)?