# Signing in with google with my app that uses flutter and firebase, doesn't show the google log in pop up, does nothing

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

When I click the "Sign in with google" Button with my app, it is meant to show the google log in popup, but instead I get this error:

````
W/DynamiteModule(15856): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.auth.api.fallback not found.
E/flutter (15856): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)
E/flutter (15856): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:607
E/flutter (15856): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:167
E/flutter (15856): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15856): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:367
E/flutter (15856): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15856): #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:244
E/flutter (15856): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15856): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:1
E/flutter (15856): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15856):```

This basically means that I cannot sign in using my app. Btw I have added a SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprint on my firebase and added the new google-services.json, still nothing.
Any help would be extremely appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was with my emulator, I reinstalled an emulator with play store pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

> This 12500 Error can be solved by adding a support email address to your project in project settings. Open link https://console.firebase.google.com/

> Select Your project and open settings tab.

> Provide a valid support email and restart your application now.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work sorry