# Facing google sso signIn with error code 12500

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor-plugin

I need to login to my application only with googleSSO login not with firebase, I have used ionic & capacitor and [googlePlus plugin](https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth) i followed all the steps for android and web, for web i am able to get the response like profile name, image etc. But when i install the signed apk into my android device a popup comes with my gmail list and on selecting any mail i am getting a response like **12500 "something went wrong"**

For android and web i am using web_client_id provided in google console

Can some one help me on this

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a duplicate of [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500).

> This 12500 Error can be solved by adding a **support email address**
> to your project in *project settings.*    Open link
> https://console.firebase.google.com/
>
> Select Your project and open settings tab.
>
> Provide a valid support email and restart your application now.

[image]

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313867/6731412))

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my requirement is not to use google firebase. i should only use Google Console, there i have added developer support mail.