# Firebase Authentication (Google SignIn) works only in my official email Id and not with any other email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I recently created a project and enabled Firebase Authentication SignIn method as Google providers and everything seems to working fine and I continued my project. Now at the final stage, I jus gave a try to SignIn with other email IDs but it doesn't work. On Debug, the result of the GoogleSignInResult `Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12500, resolution=null}`. I tried all the options that are given in the docs. Firebase Project is created under my organisation email ID and also the Google Cloud Project as well and now, SignIn in Mobile App works only with this Organisation Email ID and not with anyone else in the same Organisation or even personal google account.

Firebase Authorised Domains is same as Google Cloud OAuth Consent Screen.

Hence, I tired to create a sample app (just to see if it working) using my personal email account in firebase and it is working with all the email IDs. I am not sure why my official or organisation account is not working just like my personal account. Please share me your thoughts on this.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)? Besides that, if you understand Kotlin, then this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Did you ever manage to figure out why this was happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your API correctly on your google cloud console and added your OAuth Client ID and Secret to your Environment Variables?

If you have, in your "OAuth consent screen", what is you "publishing status"?

If you're in the testing phase, and have added "Test users", you can only login with an approved "Test user" credential.

You can try deleting all test users. This should allow any google account to login.

Another method is to delete your project on google cloud console and create a new project, than update your Google Client ID and Secret to your Environment Variables.

Your organisation's email will only work if Google is the service provider.