# OAuth with Native React and Google Console

Tags: react-native, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am making react native app which will store data in google sheet.
Storing data in sheet is available only with oauth token. Basic api token doesnt allow post requests.

For login i tried using two libraries but same error
https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin

```
@react-native-google-signin/google-signin
react-native-google-signin
```

This is my code

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  GoogleSigninButton,
  statusCodes,
} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

const WEB_CLIENT_ID = '123crnslgq7d.apps.googleusercontent.com ';
GoogleSignin.configure({
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
  webClientId: WEB_CLIENT_ID,
});

const signIn = async () => {
  try {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    console.log(userInfo)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
  }
};

function App(): JSX.Element {
  useEffect(()=>{
    signIn();
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
       Test
    </>
  )

}
```

My app shows oauth login panel, i choose the email and get this error.

```
{"nativeStackAndroid":[],
"userInfo":null,
"message":"A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred","code":"12500"}
```

I followed a bunch of tutorials to set up my project in google console, for example
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmtPTgE2_JY

Anyway:

- clientId is correct
- email i am using to login is listed as test user, and project owner
- google people api, and google sheet api is enabled in console

Any idea what I am missing?
I spent two days trying to figure this out :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313867/9839687 my problem solved by this solution

Comment: Hmm I wasnt working with FIrebase, just google console. But you may be right. Gonna take a look. Thanks